# Pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, arrays, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API (version 4) REST service where I need to pass an array of integers.

Here is my action method:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories(int[] categoryIds){
// code to retrieve categories from database
}
```

And this is the URL that I have tried:

```
/Categories?categoryids=1,2,3,4
```

Comment: I was getting a "Can't bind multiple parameters to the request's content" error when using a querystring like "/Categories?categoryids=1&categoryids=2&categoryids=3".  Hope this brings people here who were getting this same error.

Comment: @Josh Did you use [FromUri] though?
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories([FromUri] int[] categoryids){...}

Comment: @FrankGorman No, I wasn't, which was my issue.

Answer (score 746, accepted):

You just need to add **`[FromUri]`** before parameter, looks like:

```cs
GetCategories([FromUri] int[] categoryIds)
```

And send request:

```
/Categories?categoryids=1&categoryids=2&categoryids=3
```

Comment: What if I don't know how much variables I have in the array? What if it's like 1000? The request shouldn't be like that.

Comment: The server side can accept as many elements as you'd like. You have to know how many elements are in your array when you're building your URL (since you have the actual array). You can append "&categoryids=" as many times as you have elements and "overload" it.

Comment: This gives me an error "An item with the same key has already been added.".  It does however accept categoryids[0]=1&categoryids[1]=2& etc...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - @Hemanshu Bhojak: isn't it about time to take your pick?

Comment: This reason for this is due to the following statement from the [ASP.NET Web API website talking about parameter binding:](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)
"If the parameter is a “simple” type, Web API tries to get the value from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int, bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal, and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from a string."  **an int[] is not a simple type.**

Comment: This works well for me. One point. On the server code, the array parameter has to come first for it to work and any other parameters, after. When feeding in the parameters in the request, the order is unimportant.

Comment: WTF  ?categoryids=1&categoryids=2&categoryids=3 lol why not categoryids=1,2,3

Comment: @SebastianPatten It's legacy from MVC.  If you add a number of checkboxes (for example) to a html form, each with the same name, the form will be posted in the `?categoryids=1&categoryids=2&categoryids=3` format, meaning you can easily bind them to an array.

Comment: @SebastianPatten why would any framework use `categoryids=1,2,3` ?  That's a WTF itself. It breaks URI conventions and breaks if the values contain commas. The answer is simply that some framework used that as a quick-fix and some people got used to it as a convention. Other frameworks didn't.  PHP accepts `cars[]=Saab&cars[]=Audi`. Node accepts that and `cars=Saab&cars=Audi`. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string) shows just how many variations there are

Comment: @Lavel What is the verb attribute on the ws method on the server?  
[HttpGet("{Categories}")]  ?    It is unclear to me where "Categories" comes from and exactly how it is used.  Thanks.

Comment: FYI, the way to do this when using .NET Core (or at least the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` library is to change `[FromUri]` to `[FromQuery]`

Answer (score 117):

As [Filip W](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/) points out, you might have to resort to a custom model binder like this (modified to bind to actual type of param):

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories([ModelBinder(typeof(CommaDelimitedArrayModelBinder))]long[] categoryIds) 
{
    // do your thing
}

public class CommaDelimitedArrayModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var key = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
        if (val != null)
        {
            var s = val.AttemptedValue;
            if (s != null)
            {
                var elementType = bindingContext.ModelType.GetElementType();
                var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(elementType);
                var values = Array.ConvertAll(s.Split(new[] { ","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),
                    x => { return converter.ConvertFromString(x != null ? x.Trim() : x); });

                var typedValues = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, values.Length);

                values.CopyTo(typedValues, 0);

                bindingContext.Model = typedValues;
            }
            else
            {
                // change this line to null if you prefer nulls to empty arrays 
                bindingContext.Model = Array.CreateInstance(bindingContext.ModelType.GetElementType(), 0);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then you can say:

`/Categories?categoryids=1,2,3,4` and ASP.NET Web API will correctly bind your `categoryIds` array.

Comment: This may violate SRP and/or SoC, but you can easily make this also inherit from `ModelBinderAttribute` so it can be used directly instead of the laborious syntax using the `typeof()` argument. All you have to do is inherit like so: `CommaDelimitedArrayModelBinder : ModelBinderAttribute, IModelBinder` and then provide a default constructor that pushes the type definition down to the base class: `public CommaDelimitedArrayModelBinder() : base(typeof(CommaDelimitedArrayModelBinder)) { }`.

Comment: Otherwise, I really like this solution and am using it in my project, so... thanks. :)

Comment: Aa a side note, this solution doesn't work with generics like `System.Collections.Generic.List<long>` as `bindingContext.ModelType.GetElementType()` only support `System.Array` types

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: This question and the answer specifically talk about Arrays. If you need a generic list based solution, that's fairly trivial to implement. Feel free to raise a separate question if you're not sure how to go about that.

Comment: If you're using model binding, you're thinking MVC and not WebApi.  WebApi gracefully handles POST calls with json data, allows for passing complex objects with deeply nested properties while worrying about neither query parameters nor html encoding.

Comment: @codeMonkey: putting the array into the body makes good sense for a POST request, but what about GET requests? These usually have no content in the body.

Comment: Don't mean to necro this post, but did you use System.Web.ModelBinding.IModelBinder or System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder?

Comment: It was `System.Web.Mvc` AFAIK, considering the age of this post.

Comment: For anyone who is using this with newer versions of ASP.NET and MVC, this specifically uses `System.Web.Mvc` and the lines that contain `bindingContext.Model = ...` need to be changed to `bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Model = ...`

Comment: Setting value for the model in asp net core works a little bit different so this one from answer/article doesn't work, but it can be easily fixed with this [example from doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-model-binder-sample).

Comment: A little note to @sliderhouserules solution: there is no need to inherit the binder itself, one can just create a `CommaDelimetedArrayModelBinderAttribute` that will inherit from `ModelBinderAttribute` and pass the required type `CommaDelimetedArrayModelBinder` in the base constructor

Answer (score 47):

I recently came across this requirement myself, and I decided to implement an `ActionFilter` to handle this.

```
public class ArrayInputAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _parameterName;

    public ArrayInputAttribute(string parameterName)
    {
        _parameterName = parameterName;
        Separator = ',';
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(_parameterName))
        {
            string parameters = string.Empty;
            if (actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey(_parameterName))
                parameters = (string) actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[_parameterName];
            else if (actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString()[_parameterName] != null)
                parameters = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString()[_parameterName];

            actionContext.ActionArguments[_parameterName] = parameters.Split(Separator).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        }
    }

    public char Separator { get; set; }
}
```

I am applying it like so (note that I used 'id', not 'ids', as that is how it is specified in my route):

```
[ArrayInput("id", Separator = ';')]
public IEnumerable<Measure> Get(int[] id)
{
    return id.Select(i => GetData(i));
}
```

And the public url would be:

```
/api/Data/1;2;3;4
```

You may have to refactor this to meet your specific needs.

Comment: type int are hardcoded (int.Parse) in your solution . Imho, @Mrchief's solution is better

Answer (score 30):

In case someone would need - to achieve same or similar thing(like delete) via `POST` instead of `FromUri`, use `FromBody` and on client side(JS/jQuery) format param as `$.param({ '': categoryids }, true)`

c#:

```
public IHttpActionResult Remove([FromBody] int[] categoryIds)
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $.param({ '': categoryids }, true),
        url: url,
//...
});
```

The thing with `$.param({ '': categoryids }, true)` is that it .net will expect post body to contain urlencoded value like `=1&=2&=3` without parameter name, and without brackets.

Comment: No need to resort to a POST. See @Lavel answer.

Comment: There is a limit in how much data you can send in a URI. And by standard, this should not be a GET request since it is actually modifying data.

Comment: And where exactly did you see a GET here? :)

Comment: @Sofija OP says `code to retrieve categories from database`, thus the method should be a GET method, not POST.

Comment: @Azimuth But in this answer/example, it is the Remove method, not a retrieve method.

Comment: @Andrew, then it should be a `DELETE` method.

Answer (score 28):

Easy way to send array params to web api

API

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories([FromUri]int[] categoryIds){
 // code to retrieve categories from database
}
```

Jquery : send JSON object as request params

```
$.get('api/categories/GetCategories',{categoryIds:[1,2,3,4]}).done(function(response){
console.log(response);
//success response
});
```

It will generate your request URL like 
`../api/categories/GetCategories?categoryIds=1&categoryIds=2&categoryIds=3&categoryIds=4`

Comment: how is this different than the accepted answer? with the exception of implementing an ajax request via jquery which had nothing to do with the original post.

Answer (score 16):

You may try this code for you to take comma separated values / an array of values to get back a JSON from webAPI

```cs
 public class CategoryController : ApiController
 {
     public List<Category> Get(String categoryIDs)
     {
         List<Category> categoryRepo = new List<Category>();

         String[] idRepo = categoryIDs.Split(',');

         foreach (var id in idRepo)
         {
             categoryRepo.Add(new Category()
             {
                 CategoryID = id,
                 CategoryName = String.Format("Category_{0}", id)
             });
         }
         return categoryRepo;
     }
 }

 public class Category
 {
     public String CategoryID { get; set; }
     public String CategoryName { get; set; }
 }
```

Output :

```
[
{"CategoryID":"4","CategoryName":"Category_4"}, 
{"CategoryID":"5","CategoryName":"Category_5"}, 
{"CategoryID":"3","CategoryName":"Category_3"} 
]
```

Answer (score 15):

## ASP.NET Core 2.0 Solution (Swagger Ready)

### Input

```
DELETE /api/items/1,2
DELETE /api/items/1
```

### Code

#### Write the provider (how MVC knows what binder to use)

```
public class CustomBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(int[]) || context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(List<int>))
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(CommaDelimitedArrayParameterBinder));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Write the actual binder (access all sorts of info about the request, action, models, types, whatever)

```
public class CommaDelimitedArrayParameterBinder : IModelBinder
{

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        var value = bindingContext.ActionContext.RouteData.Values[bindingContext.FieldName] as string;

        // Check if the argument value is null or empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var ints = value?.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(ints);

        if(bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(List<int>))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(ints.ToList());
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

#### Register it with MVC

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    // add custom binder to beginning of collection
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomBinderProvider());
});
```

#### Sample usage with a well documented controller for Swagger

```
/// <summary>
/// Deletes a list of items.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="itemIds">The list of unique identifiers for the  items.</param>
/// <returns>The deleted item.</returns>
/// <response code="201">The item was successfully deleted.</response>
/// <response code="400">The item is invalid.</response>
[HttpDelete("{itemIds}", Name = ItemControllerRoute.DeleteItems)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task Delete(List<int> itemIds)
=> await _itemAppService.RemoveRangeAsync(itemIds);
```

EDIT: Microsoft [recommends using a TypeConverter for these kids of operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#recommendations-and-best-practices) over this approach. So follow the below posters advice and document your custom type with a SchemaFilter.

Comment: I think the MS recomendation you're talking about is satisfied by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49563970/4367683

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/pull/7967 it looks as if they added a fix to start parsing List<whatever> in the query string without a need for a special binder. Also the post you linked is not ASPNET Core and I do not think helps with my situation.

Comment: The best, non-hacky answer.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using a custom ModelBinder, you can also use a custom type with a TypeConverter.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(StrListConverter))]
public class StrList : List<string>
{
    public StrList(IEnumerable<string> collection) : base(collection) {}
}

public class StrListConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (value is string s)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                return null;
            return new StrList(s.Split(','));
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

The advantage is that it makes the Web API method's parameters very simple. You dont't even need to specify [FromUri].

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories(StrList categoryIds) {
  // code to retrieve categories from database
}
```

This example is for a List of strings, but you could do `categoryIds.Select(int.Parse)` or simply write an IntList instead.

Comment: Don't understand why this solution didn't get much votes. It is nice and clean and works with swagger without adding custom binders and stuff.

Comment: The best/cleanest answer in my opinion. Thanks PhillipM!

Comment: Now (2020/2021) simply this works
[HttpGet]
        public string GetMany([FromQuery] List<string> id)
        {
            return "something";
        }

Comment: Note that Swagger treats the array of integers as string. It works but would be nicer if Swagger would treat it as array of integers instead.

Comment: @Thieme, I think that the answer got less votes because it requires to use a custom type rather than using standard types (i.e. array of int) In general, your API should use the same pattern for all methods so it is not a problem to register a custom binder.

Comment: If the StrList object is optional meaning a null is sent. How can we instantiate a default empty list instead of NULL ?

Answer (score 9):

I originally used the solution that @Mrchief for years (it works great). But when when I added **Swagger** to my project for API documentation my end point was **NOT** showing up.

It took me a while, but this is what I came up with. It works with Swagger, and your API method signatures look cleaner:

**In the end you can do:**

```
    // GET: /api/values/1,2,3,4 

    [Route("api/values/{ids}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetIds(int[] ids)
    {
        return Ok(ids);
    }
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Allow WebApi to Use a Custom Parameter Binding
        config.ParameterBindingRules.Add(descriptor => descriptor.ParameterType == typeof(int[]) && descriptor.ActionDescriptor.SupportedHttpMethods.Contains(HttpMethod.Get)
                                                           ? new CommaDelimitedArrayParameterBinder(descriptor)
                                                           : null);

        // Allow ApiExplorer to understand this type (Swagger uses ApiExplorer under the hood)
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(int[]), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(StringToIntArrayConverter)));

        // Any existing Code ..

    }
}
```

**Create a new class: CommaDelimitedArrayParameterBinder.cs**

```
public class CommaDelimitedArrayParameterBinder : HttpParameterBinding, IValueProviderParameterBinding
{
    public CommaDelimitedArrayParameterBinder(HttpParameterDescriptor desc)
        : base(desc)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles Binding (Converts a comma delimited string into an array of integers)
    /// </summary>
    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
                                             HttpActionContext actionContext,
                                             CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var queryString = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[Descriptor.ParameterName] as string;

        var ints = queryString?.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

        SetValue(actionContext, ints);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValueProviderFactory> ValueProviderFactories { get; } = new[] { new QueryStringValueProviderFactory() };
}
```

**Create a new class: StringToIntArrayConverter.cs**

```
public class StringToIntArrayConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47123965/862011 pointed me in the right direction
- Swagger was only failing to pick my comma delimited end points when using the [Route] attribute

Comment: In-case anyone else needs info on the libraries this uses. Here is the using for "CommaDelimitedArrayParameterBinder ".
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Metadata;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
using System.Web.Http.ValueProviders;
using System.Web.Http.ValueProviders.Providers;

Answer (score 7):

I have created a custom model binder which converts any comma separated values (only primitive, decimal, float, string) to their corresponding arrays.

```
public class CommaSeparatedToArrayBinder<T> : IModelBinder
    {
        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            if (type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof(Decimal) || type == typeof(String) || type == typeof(float))
            {
                ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
                if (val == null) return false;

                string key = val.RawValue as string;
                if (key == null) { bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Wrong value type"); return false; }

                string[] values = key.Split(',');
                IEnumerable<T> result = this.ConvertToDesiredList(values).ToArray();
                bindingContext.Model = result;
                return true;
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Only primitive, decimal, string and float data types are allowed...");
            return false;
        }

        private IEnumerable<T> ConvertToDesiredArray(string[] values)
        {
            foreach (string value in values)
            {
                var val = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
                yield return val;
            }
        }
    }
```

And how to use in Controller:

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CommaSeparatedToArrayBinder<int>))] int[] ids)
        {
            return Ok(ids);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've ported it to netcore 3.1 with little effort and it works!

Accepted answer don't solve problem with need to specify param name many-many times and is the same as default operation in netcore 3.1

Answer (score 6):

```
public class ArrayInputAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] _ParameterNames;
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Separator { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// cons
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameterName"></param>
    public ArrayInputAttribute(params string[] parameterName)
    {
        _ParameterNames = parameterName;
        Separator = ",";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public void ProcessArrayInput(HttpActionContext actionContext, string parameterName)
    {
        if (actionContext.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(parameterName))
        {
            var parameterDescriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParameterName == parameterName);
            if (parameterDescriptor != null && parameterDescriptor.ParameterType.IsArray)
            {
                var type = parameterDescriptor.ParameterType.GetElementType();
                var parameters = String.Empty;
                if (actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
                {
                    parameters = (string)actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[parameterName];
                }
                else
                {
                    var queryString = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
                    if (queryString[parameterName] != null)
                    {
                        parameters = queryString[parameterName];
                    }
                }

                var values = parameters.Split(new[] { Separator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromString).ToArray();
                var typedValues = Array.CreateInstance(type, values.Length);
                values.CopyTo(typedValues, 0);
                actionContext.ActionArguments[parameterName] = typedValues;
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        _ParameterNames.ForEach(parameterName => ProcessArrayInput(actionContext, parameterName));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [ArrayInput("tagIDs")]
    [Route("api/v1/files/{fileID}/tags/{tagIDs}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage RemoveFileTags(Guid fileID, Guid[] tagIDs)
    {
        _FileRepository.RemoveFileTags(fileID, tagIDs);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Request uri

```
http://localhost/api/v1/files/2a9937c7-8201-59b7-bc8d-11a9178895d0/tags/BBA5CD5D-F07D-47A9-8DEE-D19F5FA65F63,BBA5CD5D-F07D-47A9-8DEE-D19F5FA65F63
```

Comment: @Elsa Could you please point out which piece you can't understand? 
I think the code is quite clear to explanation it self.
It's hard for me to explain this all in English, sorry.

Comment: @Steve Czetty here's my reconstructed version, thanks for your idea

Comment: Will it work with `/` as the seperator?
Then you could have: http://dns/root/mystuff/path/to/some/resource mapped  to `public string GetMyStuff(params string[] pathBits)`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to list/ array of integers easiest way to do this is accept the comma(,) separated list of string and convert it to list of integers.Do not forgot to mention [FromUri] attriubte.your url look like:

> ...?ID=71&accountID=1,2,3,289,56

```
public HttpResponseMessage test([FromUri]int ID, [FromUri]string accountID)
{
    List<int> accountIdList = new List<int>();
    string[] arrAccountId = accountId.Split(new char[] { ',' });
    for (var i = 0; i < arrAccountId.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
           accountIdList.Add(Int32.Parse(arrAccountId[i]));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you use `List<string>` instead of just `string`? it will only have one string in it which is `1,2,3,289,56` in your example. I will suggest an edit.

Comment: Worked for me. I was surprised my controller wouldn't bind to a `List<Guid>` automatically though. Note in Asp.net Core the annotation is `[FromQuery]`, and it is not needed.

Comment: For a one-line Linq version:
int[] accountIdArray = accountId.Split(',').Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToArray();
I'd avoid the catch since it will mask somebody passing in bad data.

Answer (score 4):

Make the method type [HttpPost], create a model that has one int[] parameter, and post with json:

```
/* Model */
public class CategoryRequestModel 
{
    public int[] Categories { get; set; }
}

/* WebApi */
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCategories(CategoryRequestModel model)
{
    HttpResponseMessage resp = null;

    try
    {
        var categories = //your code to get categories

        resp = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, categories);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        resp = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
    }

    return resp;
}

/* jQuery */
var ajaxSettings = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Categories',
    data: JSON.serialize({Categories: [1,2,3,4]}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //get categories from data
    }
};

$.ajax(ajaxSettings);
```

Comment: You're wrapping your array in a class - that will work fine (MVC/WebAPI notwithstanding). The OP was about binding to array without a wrapper class.

Comment: The original problem doesn't say anything about doing it without a wrapper class, just that they wanted to use query params for complex objects.  If you go down that path too far you'll get to a point where you need the API to pick up a really complex js object, and query param's will fail you.  Might as well learn to do it the way that will work every time.

Comment: `public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories(int[] categoryIds){` - yeah you could interpret in different ways I suppose. But many a times, I do not want to create wrapper classes for the sake of creating wrappers. If you have complex objects, then that will just work. Supporting these simpler cases is what doesn't work out of the box, hence the OP.

Comment: Doing this via `POST` is actually against the REST paradigm. Thus such API wouldn't be a REST API.

Comment: @Azimuth give me a paradigm in one hand, what works with .NET in the other

Answer (score 4):

Or you could just pass a string of delimited items and put it into an array or list on the receiving end.

Answer (score 3):

I addressed this issue this way.

I used a post message to the api to send the list of integers as data.

Then I returned the data as an ienumerable.

The sending code is as follows:

```
public override IEnumerable<Contact> Fill(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    IEnumerable<Contact> result = null;
    if (ids!=null&&ids.Count()>0)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49520/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                String _endPoint = "api/" + typeof(Contact).Name + "/ListArray";

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<IEnumerable<int>>(_endPoint, ids).Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Contact>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The receiving code is as follows:

```
// POST api/<controller>
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ListArray")]
public IEnumerable<Contact> Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    IEnumerable<Contact> result = null;
    if (ids != null && ids.Count() > 0)
    {
        return contactRepository.Fill(ids);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works just fine for one record or many records.  The fill is an overloaded method using DapperExtensions:

```
public override IEnumerable<Contact> Fill(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    IEnumerable<Contact> result = null;
    if (ids != null && ids.Count() > 0)
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = ConnectionProvider.OpenConnection())
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            var predicate = Predicates.Field<Contact>(f => f.id, Operator.Eq, ids);
            result = dbConnection.GetList<Contact>(predicate);
            dbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This allows you to fetch data from a composite table (the id list), and then return the records you are really interested in from the target table.

You could do the same with a view, but this gives you a little more control and flexibility.

In addition, the details of what you are seeking from the database are not shown in the query string.  You also do not have to convert from a csv file.

You have to keep in mind when using any tool like the web api 2.x interface is that the get, put, post, delete, head, etc., functions have a general use, but are not restricted to that use.

So, while post is generally used in a create context in the web api interface, it is not restricted to that use.  It is a *regular* html call that can be used for any purpose permitted by html practice.

In addition, the details of what is going on are hidden from those "prying eyes" we hear so much about these days.

The flexibility in naming conventions in the web api 2.x interface and use of regular web calling means you send a call to the web api that misleads snoopers into thinking you are really doing something else.  You can use "POST" to really retrieve data, for example.

Answer (score 2):

All other solutions need too much work. I was trying to use `IEnumerable<long>` or `long[]` in a `HttpGet` method parameter, but I see no point of doing all the work just to make the signature of the handler method parameter `long[]`. I ended up just making it string, and then separated it within the handler. Took me one line.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeHandler(string idsString)
{
    var ids = idsString.Split(',').Select(x => long.Parse(x));
```

Now you can just pass the numbers like

```
.../SomeHandler?idsString=123,456,789,012
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create an attribute to validate strings, it does a bunch of extra common features, including regex validation that you can use to check for numbers only and then later I convert to integers as needed...

This is how you use:

```
public class MustBeListAndContainAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private Regex regex = null;
    public bool RemoveDuplicates { get; }
    public string Separator { get; }
    public int MinimumItems { get; }
    public int MaximumItems { get; }

    public MustBeListAndContainAttribute(string regexEachItem,
        int minimumItems = 1,
        int maximumItems = 0,
        string separator = ",",
        bool removeDuplicates = false) : base()
    {
        this.MinimumItems = minimumItems;
        this.MaximumItems = maximumItems;
        this.Separator = separator;
        this.RemoveDuplicates = removeDuplicates;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(regexEachItem))
            regex = new Regex(regexEachItem, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var listOfdValues = (value as List<string>)?[0];

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(listOfdValues))
        {
            if (MinimumItems > 0)
                return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
            else
                return null;
        };

        var list = new List<string>();

        list.AddRange(listOfdValues.Split(new[] { Separator }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        if (RemoveDuplicates) list = list.Distinct().ToList();

        var prop = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(validationContext.MemberName);
        prop.SetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, list);
        value = list;

        if (regex != null)
            if (list.Any(c => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c) || !regex.IsMatch(c)))
                return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added the *Query* key (Refit lib) in the property for the request.

> [Query(CollectionFormat.Multi)]

```
public class ExampleRequest
{
       
        [FromQuery(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }               
       
        [AliasAs("category")]
        [Query(CollectionFormat.Multi)]
        public List<string> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How would the request look like for this solution and does this work with Swagger Docs?