# ASP.NET WebAPI method with two parameters, one array

Tags: asp.net-web-api

i'm new to WebAPI and had a few qeustion to custom method calling.
So, im working with Entity Framework and created a WebAPI with basic CRUD methods.
But now i want to add some custom methods, is it possible to call arrays as parameters? And when yes, how?

This is my method:

```
public void AddRoles(Guid userid, Guid[] roleids)
```

So how it is possible to call this method through webapi?
I tryed it with

```
http://localhost:60690/api/MyController/AddRoles...
```

And is it possible to call void method? What is the response?

thanks and greetings,
Joerg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://localhost:60690/api/MyController/AddRoles?userid=<user id guid here>&roleids=<guid1 here>&roleids=<guid2 here>...
```

As for the void method, of course it is possible, response will be with 200 code and empty body.

Comment: and where is the userid in your example?

Comment: @JörgZeyn, just skipped it for space sake. Behind the dots in other words. Will it be better if I add it?

Comment: just one last question: i think i got a routing problem now, he is always looking for `GetUserById(System.Guid)` instead of AddRoles. Here is my route config `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "CustomApiActions",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );`

Comment: @JörgZeyn, routing seems OK, most likely it just unable to find necessary action. Have you decorated the action (AddRoles that is) with `HttpGet` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

For GET you can refer to the following SO question:

[How to pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-to-integers-to-a-asp-net-web-api-rest-service)

If you want to try to use POST then continue to read:

You should create a DTO for your parameters like such:

```
public class AddRoleModel
{
    Guid UserId { get; set; }
    Guid[] RoleIds { get; set; }
}
```

Change your method to accept accept POST and your new AddRoleModel DTO instead of the two different parameters like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddRoles(AddRoleModel model)
{
   ...
}
```

And POST the json for that model to the method

json could look like this:

```
{    
    UserId: "{guid}",
    RoleIds: ["{some guid}", "{some other guid}"]
}
```

Comment: I believe OP asked about `get` request

Comment: what are the benefits of this example?