# Pass array of integers to Get / ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know how to pass arrays to Get function like this: `/?index=1&index=5&index=3`

But I need to be able to receive arrays like this: `/?index=[1,5,3]`

Or something similarly short. Is there anything I can use?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string  One way to test it would be to create a form with a GET action with a multi-select, select multiple options, and see how it formats the request and how the server interprets it.

Comment: Have you tried the alternative solutions form here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-of-integers-to-a-asp-net-web-api-rest-service?rq=1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom `ModelBinder`:

```
public class JsArrayStyleModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<string[]>(value.AttemptedValue);
    }
}
```

Then register it in your `Global.asax`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string[]), new JsArrayStyleModelBinder());
```

Or directly on your `Action` parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Show([ModelBinder(typeof(JsArrayStyleModelBinder))] string[] indexes)
```

Comment: You could also use `String.Split` instead of the `JavaScriptSerializer`.