# ASP.NET Web Api 2 - arrays in a get request

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I am converting a project that is using Service Stack to ASP.NET Web API 2. What ServiceStack allowed me to do is send JSON stringified objects in the URI of the GET request.

This is the class that I have:

```
public class ShowsByTitles 
{
    public string Query { set; get; }
    public List<IgnoreShowIds> IgnoreIds { set; get; }
    public List<long> IgnoreTypes { set; get; }
    public List<long> OnlyTypes { set; get; } 

    public long Id { get; private set; }
    public string FilterName { set; get; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> FilterData { get; set; }

    public ShowsByTitles()
    {
        IgnoreIds = new List<IgnoreShowIds>();
    }
}

public class IgnoreShowIds
    {
        public long ShowTypeId { set; get; }
        public long ShowId { set; get; }
    }
```

With Service Stack I was able to make this request:
http://domain.com/api/ShowsByTitles?Query=something&IgnoreIds=[{ShowTypeId:1,ShowId:5}]&IgnoreTypes=[]&OnlyTypes=[2,3]

How can I make this style to work with the Web API 2? I tried with this approach: [Pass array of integers to Get / ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727932/pass-array-of-integers-to-get-asp-net-web-api)
but it is not working.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Curious as to why would want to send this data in query string rather than the request body using POST? Web API doesn't have support for JSV format which ServiceStack has. I am not sure if JSV is a well known format. You would need to have custom implementation in Web API if you plan to do what Service stack was providing...

Comment: Because I need to send an array as option to GET something. I'm building a RESTful style API, and POST doesn't make sense. Basically, I needed to send an array of integers, like /api/shows?genres=[100,300,101,305]. I ended up with a custom implementation.

Comment: I'm curious what custom implementation you ended up with. If you can, please post it as the answer.