# Passing array of integers to WebAPI method in URI params?

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

I have the following:

```
    [HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteFolder(int[] ids)
    {
```

and I'm trying to use this:

```
DELETE http://localhost:24144/api/folder/1483;
DELETE http://localhost:24144/api/folder/[1483]
```

but these are coming up as null within the delete method - how do I send the data without putting it in the body (since this is a DELETE request)?

My routing has this:

```
            routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "Folder",
           routeTemplate: "api/folder/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Folder", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9981330/1405720

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nevermind, I found this:

http://blog.codelab.co.nz/2012/10/16/passing-arrays-into-asp-net-web-api-as-parameters/

Couldn't find an answer on SO though so I'll leave it here.

*Exerpt from the above linked page:*

```
[HttpGet()]
public HttpResponseMessage FindByMembers([FromUri]Int32[] ids = null)
{
   //Do stuff
    return Request.CreateResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

> The Url will be http://mywebsite/api/mycontroller/findbymembers/?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to have Uri like `api/folder/[1,2,3]`, the same parameter binding example mentioned in the below post's answer can be used here too :

[How to send an array via a URI using Attribute Routing in Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798281/attribute-routing-in-webapi)

**Note**: You would need to change the following line to look for 'id' route variable rather than 'ids' as your route template here is 'api/folder/{id}'.

```
string idsAsString = actionContext.Request.GetRouteData().Values["id"].ToString();
```