# Can we pass array as parameter to Delete() action in WebAPI from jQuery Ajax call?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, restangular

I am using WebAPI and implemented a controller method Delete with HTTP verb as [HTTPDELETE]. Please find the syntax below:

```
[HttpDelete]
public Resonse Delete([FromBody]Guid[] input)
{
     \\method processing
}
```

I am using RestAngular to call this method.

```
let so = {"asde-wert-wedc-ewsdc", "asde-wert-wedc-ewsdc"};
Students.one(1234).remove(so);
```

When I am trying to run it. I am getting 500 internal server error.

I need to pass an array of Guid to my Delete method in controller using restangular.

Comment: Try to pass the ids via querystring and use `[FromUri]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing array of integers to WebAPI method in URI params?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779111/passing-array-of-integers-to-webapi-method-in-uri-params)

Comment: `HTTP DELETE` requests doesn't have a body.

Comment: HTTP Method RFC Request Has Body Response Has Body Safe
DELETE RFC 7231 No Yes No

Comment: Thanks for your response guys, I don't want to pass values in URL, my list of input parameters can be very large in size so I want to send them as a part of body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hit and trials I got the answer. I need to apply custom operation in restangular:

Get all the elements in an array

```
this.objectlist = [];
```

Pass the array as a parameter.

```
this.restangular.all(this.route).customOperation("remove",this.route, null, {"Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}, {objectIds:objectlist});
```

Please do mention content type otherwise it will not work.