# Javascript tradition querystring parameter in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am calling a web api method.

API method:

```
//get
public bool GetShoppingElementDetails(ElementSearchParameter elementSearchParameter)
{

}

class ElementSearchParameter{
   public string name;
   public list<int> ids;
}
```

Actually that method is a get method, So how can i pass multidimention array parameter to that function,

I thinking like, the jquery framework is converting the complete object into correct querystring using "traditional=true", so that the mvc controller parsing that perfectly.

The same way in c# i want to do.
Something like below,

```
ElementSearchParameter toSearch = new ElementSearchParameter{};

//convert the tosearch object into string object (parsing like jquery)
string toSearchString = ...

   HttpResponseMessage response = httpManager.Client.GetAsync(string.Format(_routePrefixMeta + "/OrderOffering/Elements/search/{1}", programID, toSearchString)).Result;
            return httpManager.ConstructData<List<OfferElementType>>(response);
```

Comment: I am not calling the controller method from javascript, calling from c#. (WEB-API)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting to know how to pass multiple ids on a query string and have them resolved as an IEnumerable?

I think the only way to do this is to use a custom ModelBinder. You can find an example for something similar [How to pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-of-integers-to-a-asp-net-web-api-rest-service)

Then - as stated in the above link - you can say: /Categories?categoryids=1,2,3,4 and ASP.NET Web API will correctly bind your categoryIds array.

Comment: Thanks, I want to pass collection of complex object, Not collection of int, string, etc....

Comment: Hi, same thing then except you need a way of serializing them into a string format then use the model binder to parse out your object