# Passing large parameters to c# webapi and return result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How i can pass 500 or even 1000 URL each time to c# webapi and return a result?
should i use get method or post method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post array of integer in body.

If you are using jquery to do the post, you can do something like below.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: [1, 2, 3]
});
```

In your Api -

```
public HttpResponse Post(int[] ids){}
```

Comment: the problem is length of params, as i mentioned the params are about 1000 URL and earch url is 100 character length, so easily exceeded the 2048 URL length limitation

Comment: If you do a HttpPost it will not hit the url length limit. I think it is hitting the url max limit as you are passing parameters in the url to Http GET method

Comment: but if HttpPost used, how the results(in this case array of URLs) is returned?

Comment: Instead of returning HttpResponse, you can return list.  you can return list  type from a post method.

Answer (score 0):

First step [How to pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-of-integers-to-a-asp-net-web-api-rest-service)

You need a post method in your controller. And receive an array of strings.

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories([FromUri] int[] categoryIds)
```

and send request

```
/Categories?categoryids=1&categoryids=2&categoryids=3
```

Then in your method do the calculations and return a result as usual

Comment: I need to pass about 1000 URL and each URL length is about 100 character, thus total webapi params length reach about 100,000 character that is more than standard URL length

Comment: Is just an example, you can also pass an object to your api as string[] using Jquey AJAX function.

Comment: the problem is length of params, as i mentioned the params are about 1000 URL and earch url is 100 character length, so easily exceeded the 2048 URL length limitation