# The AttemptedValue of my custom modelbinder contains both key and value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I'm following the answer provided by Mrchief in this question:

[How to pass an array of integers to a asp.net web api rest service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-of-integers-to-a-asp-net-web-api-rest-service)

The problem I'm experiencing is that the AttemptedValue contains the **key** of the array (see screenshot below).

[image: screenshot: visual studio]

The code that converts this string into an array expects the AttemptedValue string to be like this:

```
"123, 435, 234"
```

So what's going on here?

---

#### Edit

The url:

```
https://localhost:44301/api/sickleaves/sick/multiple/employeeIds=123,435,234
```

The endpoint signature:

```
[Route("api/sickleaves/sick/multiple/{employeeIds}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostSick([ModelBinder(typeof(CommaDelimitedArrayModelBinder))] int[] employeeIds)
```

Comment: Just as a sanity check, can you show the raw request URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have entirely different situation from what you have linked. In the link they use query string parameters:

```
/Categories?categoryids=1,2,3,4
```

Here key is `categoryids` and value is `1,2,3,4`.

What you are using is route parameter:

```
multiple/{employeeIds}
multiple/employeeIds=123,435,234
```

So here key is whatever is declared in a `{}` placeholder in route, `employeeIds` in this case, and value is what is being passed instead of the placeholder in actual url, `employeeIds=123,435,234`.

To make you custom binder relevant, you need to:

1. Either switch to query string: `multiple?employeeIds=123,435,234`
2. Or change the URL: `multiple/123,435,234` (not sure it will work though, but feel free to give it a try)