# Call WebApi action with a list of parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Web API code

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetMore([FromUri] Int32[] dd)
{
   return "";
}
```

I need to be able to call this web api passing in an array of integers

The route at the WebApiconfig is as follows

```
config.EnableCors();

// Web API configuration and services
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
```

I try to access the method with the URL

1. http://localhost/testApplication/api/questionnaire/GetMore/dd=1
   Calls the method but the dd array list is empty that is no data is present in the dd array.
2. http://localhost/testApplication/api/questionnaire/GetMore/?dd=1&dd=2&dd=3 i get an error

> {"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters
>   dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable
>   type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'WebAPI.Services.Controllers.Questionnaire Get(Int32)' in
>   'WebAPI.Services.Controllers.QuestionnaireController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter."}

None of them seem to work . I am sure im doing something wrong. Just not sure what that is ?

Comment: Have you tried passing parameters as `http://localhost/testApplication/api/questionnaire/GetMore/dd[]=1 `?

Comment: Your question [was answered before on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-of-integers-to-a-asp-net-web-api-rest-service).

Comment: http://localhost/testApplication/api/questionnaire/GetMore?dd=1&dd=2&dd=3 <= use this

Comment: I have test these code without the code before `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute`,and it works fine with the url end with `GetMore/?dd=1&dd=2&dd=3`,so there must be something happened in prev code

Comment: I try the solution mentioned at 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11100414/581157 i get the error

{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'WebAPI.Services.Controllers.Questionnaire Get(Int32)' in 'WebAPI.Services.Controllers.QuestionnaireController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}

Also the post does not contain an Answer Accepted