# How to pass parameters to array class in webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to asp.net mvc webapi.I am create one webapi service.In this service  I am sending parameter as an array class.

Below is my service :

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public HttpResponseMessage addBusOrder(string UserUniqueID, int PlatFormID,
                                       string DeviceID, int RouteScheduleId,
                                       string JourneyDate, int FromCityid,
                                       int ToCityid, int TyPickUpID,
                                       Contactinfo Contactinfo, passenger[] pass)
{
    //done some work here
}

public class Contactinfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phoneno { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
}

public class passenger
{
    public string passengerName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Fare { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Seatno { get; set; }
    //public string Seattype { get; set; }
    // public bool Isacseat { get; set; }
}
```

Now how to pass `passenger` and `contactinfo`  parameters to the above service.

Is there any changes in webapiconfig file?
 i want to pass passenger details like this:

```
passengername="pavan",
age="23",
Gender="M",

passengername="kumar",
Gender="M",
Age="22
```

Comment: @Webruster please see my code.and help me.

Comment: please any one help me.iam trying  this last 2 days still I am not getting answer

Comment: Hi @Anil Kumar,  are the passengers identified by `passengerName`? I mean, does each passenger have unique name?

Comment: @jhmt yes.each passenger have unque name

Comment: @jhmt I want to pass like this:  passengername="pavan",Age="23",Gender="M",passengername="kumar",age="22",gender="m"

Comment: @AnilKumar Are you using "GET" or "POST" for the case you are trying? Are you calling this from client code or C#. If possible post a sample calling code.

Comment: @AnilKumar I think this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-of-integers-to-a-asp-net-web-api-rest-service) is useful for GET case.

Comment: @SivaGopal I want to use post method. i want to pass parameters like this passengername="pavan",age="24",gender="m",passengername="kumar",agr="24",gender="m". how to pass like this

Comment: @jhmt i want to use post method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be much neater if you can create model of your parameter. To pass them from client side, you need to format them using one of data-interchange format. I prefer use JSON provided by Newtonsoft.Json library. Sending process is handled by HttpClient class provided by System.Net.Http namespace. Here is some sample:

**Server Side**

```
    //Only request with Post Verb that can contain body
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public HttpResponseMessage addBusOrder([FromBody]BusOrderModel)
    {
        //done some work here
    }

    //You may want to separate model into a class library so that server and client app can share the same model
        public class BusOrderModel
        {
            public string UserUniqueID { get; set; }
            public int PlatFormID { get; set; }
            public string DeviceID { get; set; }
            public int RouteScheduleId { get; set; }
            public string JourneyDate { get; set; }
            public int FromCityid { get; set; }
            public int ToCityid { get; set; }
            public int TyPickUpID { get; set; }
            public Contactinfo ContactInfo { get; set; }
            public passenger[] pass { get; set; }
        }
```

**Client Side**

```
    var busOrderModel = new BusOrderModel();
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(busOrderModel), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler, true))
            {
              client.BaseAddress = new Uri("yourdomain");
              client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                  new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

              return await client.PostAsync(new Uri("yourdomain/controller/addBusOrder"), content);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

First, since you are passing two objects as parameters we'll need a new class to hold them (because we can only bind one parameter to the request's content):

```
public class PassengersContact
{
    public Passenger[] Passengers { get; set; }
    public Contactinfo Contactinfo { get; set; }
}
```

and now for your controller (this is just a test controller):

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    // I prefer using attribute routing
    [Route("addBusOrder")]
    // FromUri means that the parameter comes from the uri of the request
    // FromBody means that the parameter comes from body of the request
    public IHttpActionResult addBusOrder([FromUri]string userUniqueId,
                                            [FromUri]int platFormId,
                                            [FromUri]string deviceId, [FromUri]int routeScheduleId,
                                            [FromUri]string journeyDate, [FromUri]int fromCityid,
                                            [FromUri]int toCityid, [FromUri]int tyPickUpId,
                                            [FromBody]PassengersContact passengersContact)
    {
        // Just for testing: I'm returning what was passed as a parameter
        return Ok(new
        {
            UserUniqueID = userUniqueId,
            PlatFormID = platFormId,
            RouteScheduleId = routeScheduleId,
            JourneyDate = journeyDate,
            FromCityid = fromCityid,
            ToCityid = toCityid,
            TyPickUpID = tyPickUpId,
            PassengersContact = passengersContact
        });
    }
}
```

Your request should look something like this:

```
POST http://<your server's URL>/api/addBusOrder?userUniqueId=a&platFormId=10&deviceId=b&routeScheduleId=11&journeyDate=c&fromCityid=12&toCityid=13&tyPickUpId=14
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 110

{
    "passengers" : [{
            "passengerName" : "name",
            "age" : 52
            /* other fields go here */
        }
    ],
    "contactinfo" : {
        "name" : "contact info name",
        /* other fields go here */
    }
}
```

Notice the `api/addBusOrder` comes from concatenating the values of the `RoutePrefix/Route` attributes.

Comment: sometimes I want to send more passengers.then how  to send passengers data dynamically

Comment: The passengers property is an array so you can pass as many passengers as you want in the Json array