# May I pass list as a parameter in web api method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

```
public static Document GetDocument(List<long> IdList)
{
          //my code
}
```

I am passing the parameter  from  UI as:-

```
 getMulipleDocument: function (documentId) {
            return $http({
                url: apiUrl + "Info/GetDocument?IdList=" + documentId,});
```

> **Bug:- parameter is coming as null in web api method.** May I pass the list as parameter in Web api method?

Comment: Refer following question and you can derive the ansver.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 1):

Do some few modification in your code. Use FromUri to build your list

```
public static Document GetDocument([FromUri]List<long> IdList)
{
          //my code
}
```

Build url like this

```
var requestUrl = apiUrl + "Info/GetDocument?IdList=" + id1 + "&IdList=" + id2;
```

Build `requestUrl` like query string starting with first id by `?IdList=` and then append next ids to url by using  `&IdList=`

In above case you can pass only one id as well bu using only `?IdList=` and followed by your id