# From route configuration to attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I have the following route configured in my ASP.NET Web API 2 Project:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "1MandatoryStringParameter",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{data}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { data = @".+?" }
```

It is used with the following controller method (notice the [ArrayInput](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17553324/15186) attribute):

```
[ArrayInput("data",Separator = ',')]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int[] data)
{
...
}
```

I would like to use Attribute routing instead.

I tried to replace the call to **MapHttpRoute** with the following attributes:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/ActionsForItemTypesList/{data:regex(.+?)}", Name = "1MandatoryStringParameter")]
```

Out of the box it does not work. I can't reach my method with an URL like:

```
api/ActionsForItemTypesList/1,2
```

If get a 404 Method not found.

This is working fine with route configuration.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT : fixed the client URL.

**EDIT 2** : This is an [ApiExplorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.apiexplorer(v=vs.118).aspx) Issue (Swashbuckle leverage ApiExplorer)

If I modify the Route attribute and remove the parameter (ie. {data}) the ApiDescription becomes available.

Comment: Two things. You can create a custom route constraint and a custom model binder for the int array. [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled attribute routing:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Also in your `Route` attribute you have specified that the `data` parameter must be part of the path and not a query string. So make sure that you are calling the action correctly from the client:

```
api/ActionsForItemTypesList/1,2
```

Also notice that the prefix that you indicated in your Route attribute is `api/ActionsForItemTypesList` and not `api/Controller` like you were trying to invoke it.

Comment: Attribute routing is enabled and the call from the client is done like you say. For what its worth, I'm using Swashbuckle and Route Debugger. With attribute routing, the method is missing from the swagger doc.

Comment: I have just created a new Web API project, removed global routing, enabled attribute routing, decorated the the controller action with this attribute and it worked without any issues. Try doing it in a clean project and progressively add stuff until you find what is causing the issue.

Comment: URL fixed. For now I'm using a mixture of global and attribute routing. My goal is to only use attribute routing.

Comment: Can you try disabling global routing to see if somehow it might be interfering with the attribute route? In theory both should work together but in practice it is not recommended to mix them.

Comment: I created a new Web API project, removed the default global route, enabled attribute routing, decorated the conroller action, then added the swashbuckle Nuget. Same result, the action is missing from the swagger doc.

Comment: Before adding the Swagger NuGet are you able to invoke the controller action?

Comment: I'm indeed able to invoke the action using fiddler / Route debugger with or without Swashbuckle. I was misled by swagger that seems to fail discovering the action.

Comment: Yes, your question was about Web API and attribute based routing initially. You may consider closing this thread and opening a new one specifically for Web API and Swagger integration.