# How do I handle multiple parameters as an OR in a Web API querystring?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

Suppose I have this URL:

```
api.XXX.com/cities?risk=a,b&rating=x,y
```

What I want is a list of cities with a Risk category of A or B AND a Rating of X or Y. How should I implement this?

I understand I can get the values of the Risk and Rating keys but then what? Is it best to simply parse the string and use a `switch` statement? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Easiest way is to post the data inside the request body as JSON instead of query strings.

Comment: @Win - I considered that but everything I read points to this being a GET. Plus, it's easier for me to get support if this is a read-only API. Using POST would likely raise some flags and complicate discussions.

Comment: You cannot construct that kind of complex object in query string.

Comment: @Win - I might be missing what you're saying but I have the above example working in code. I'm asking the question because it doesn't feel like a good design. Are you saying it's technically a bad idea, not recommended for REST design or something else?

Comment: I thought you want to post array of cities like this - `[{city: "New York", risk: "a", rating: "x"}, {city: "Chicago", risk: "b", rating: "y"}, {city: "LA", risk: "a", rating: "x"}]`

Comment: @Win - No, this is for passing the criteria to GET a list of cities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more standard approach would be:

```
api.XXX.com/cities?risks=a&risks=b&ratings=x&ratings=y
```

Which could be handled by a controller action something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SearchCities(
    List<string> risks,
    List<string> ratings)
{
    var results = this.dbContext.Cities.AsQueryable();
    if(risks.Any()) 
    {
        results = results.Where(c => c.Risks.Any(cr => risks.Contains(cr.Code));
    }
    if(ratings.Any())
    {
        results = results.Where(c => ratings.Contains(c.Rating));
    }
    ...
}
```

Similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11100414/120955).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a POCO to represent the options that this endpoint will be receiving:

```
public class CitySearchOptions
{
   public List<string> Risk { get; set; }
   public List<string> Rating { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use the `[FromUri]` attribute in your controller signature to have the query string be automatically deserialized into your POCO. From there you can easily implement logic to act on the received values.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SearchCities([FromUri] CitySearchOptions options)
```

Note that the above is psuedo code and might not work for you out of the box without a few tweaks to the format of your query string. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api) suggests that for list based query params you should prefer a format like this:

```
/cities?risk=a&risk=b&rating=x&rating=y
```