# Always getting 404 when passing an array to a .Net Core Web API method

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I cannot seem to pass an array of values to my Web API method for some reason. Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet("api/values/get/{ids}")]
public JsonResult GetValues(string[] valueIds)
{
   //Do something
}
```

I have tried calling this via the following URLs:

- http://localhost:5001/api/values/get/?valueIds=das&valueIds=ewq
- http://localhost:5001/api/values/get/?ids=das&ids=ewq
- http://localhost:5001/api/values/get?valueIds=das&valueIds=ewq
- http://localhost:5001/api/values/get?ids=das&ids=ewq

When I call it via the following URLs, I get no 404 and the method is actually called, however, the array is empty:

- http://localhost:5001/api/values/get/valueIds=das&valueIds=ewq
- http://localhost:5001/api/values/get/ids=das&ids=ewq

I have also tried adding the Attribute [FromQuery] to the front of my parameters in the method signatures like this:

```
public JsonResult GetValues([FromQuery]string[] valueIds)
```

I cannot seem to get it to work even though every tutorial out there says it should. Ripping my hair out here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api

Comment: I have tried the exact same URL from the accepted answer on that post (It's the third one in my question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `{ids}` prefix because the action selector expects `ids` parameter but you don't pass it in the action.

```
[HttpGet("api/values/get")]
public JsonResult GetValues(string[] valueIds)
{
   //Do something
}
```

And apply the request like this;

```
http://localhost:5001/api/values/get?valueIds=das&valueIds=ewq
```

Comment: This works. But I don't understand why it works when I pass only a single parameter. For example: [HttpGet("api/values/get/byparent/{parentId}")]. When I call this method with the URL http://localhost:5001/api/values/byparent/dsadasda, the method gets called and the parameter is passed.

Comment: "dsadasda" is passed as "parentId" parameter. But in the question case, there is no parameter with named "ids".

Answer (score 1):

So let's break appart what you have:

```
[HttpGet("api/values/get/{ids}")]
public JsonResult GetValues(string[] valueIds)
{
   //Do something
}
```

1. I would reccomend removing the `/get` because your method of request is `get` in `HttpGet`
2. Your specified route implies a passed `ids`(it's just a variable same as `get` it can only be singular) i.e:

http://localhost:5001/api/values/get/id

The examples that you have shown.

http://localhost:5001/api/values/get/?valueIds=das&valueIds=ewq

`get/?valueIds=das&valueIds=ewq` doesn't even specify`{ids}`

so far your route of `/get/{ids}` is redundant.

Try

```
[HttpGet("api/values")]
public JsonResult GetValues(string[] valueIds)
{
   //Do something
}
```

Query: http://localhost:5001/api/values?valueIds=das&valueIds=ewq

I'd recommend to read up on [REST API naming conventions](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but I think you need to name the query params with the []-Suffix. Like that:

`http://localhost:5001/api/values/get?valueIds[]=das&valueIds[]=ewq`

Otherwise you can easily check what your API except with the UrlHelper. Just generate yourself an url:

`var url = Url.Action("GetValues", new { valueIds = new [] { "das", "ewq" } });`