# How to send List<enum> to API

Tags: asp.net

I need to receive a list of status in a api, but I don't how. I tried this:
[image]

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("BuscarPropostasPorStatus")]
    [Authorize]
    public IHttpActionResult BuscarPropostasPorStatus(List<Status> status, string inicial="1900-01-01", string final="2099-01-01")
    {
        try
        {

            var dataInicial = Convert.ToDateTime(inicial);
            var dataFinal = Convert.ToDateTime(final);
            var usuarioId = new Guid(_token.PegarIdUsuario(HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()));

            return Ok(_sellIn.BuscarPropostasPorStatus(usuarioId, status, dataInicial, dataFinal));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new BadRequestCustom(e.Message);
        }
    }


public enum Status  
{
    AguardandoEnvio,
    AguardandoAprovacao,
    Aprovado,
    Rejeitado,
    Devolvido,
    Deletado
}
```

http://localhost:60606/PedidoSellIn/BuscarPropostasPorStatus?status=[0,1]
http://localhost:60606/PedidoSellIn/BuscarPropostasPorStatus?status=0&status=1

but the parameter is only null

Comment: Can you show us the code that call this api?

Comment: yes, i call in those links below the code, in ask. i try status=[0,1] and status=0&status=1

Comment: This looks somewhat similar to your problem [Pass an array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: let me know if this helped or not.

Comment: i can't use this because the enun can't receive int this way, but i find a alternative

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue punting a annotation in list. 
[image]