# passing an array to a asp net core web api action method HttpGet

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to send an array of integers to my action method the code looks like so:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ServicesByCategoryIds([FromQuery] int[] ids)
    {
        var services = await _accountsUow.GetServiceProfilesByCategoryIdsAsync(ids);
        return Ok(services);
    }
```

I call the method like so: https://localhost:44343/api/accounts/servicesbycategoryids?ids=1&ids=2

but always get en empty array when I call this method even tho I pass the ids in the query string. I am using .net core 2.1.

everything I have googled suggests that this is in fact the way this is done. . . 
is there something I am missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Binding failed for `Array` parameter is a known issue under `Asp.Net Core 2.1` which has been recorded [Array or List in query string does not get parsed #7712](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7712).

For a tempory workaround, you could set the `FromQuery Name Property` like below:

```
        [HttpGet()]
    [Route("ServicesByCategoryIds")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ServicesByCategoryIds([FromQuery(Name = "ids")]int[] ids)
    {            
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: also seems to work when I remove ApiControllerAttribute as suggested in the discussion you've linked.

Comment: Helps a lot !! Thank you

Comment: Recommend using newer answers from yshehab or Plamen Yovchev below

Answer (score 6):

A slight variation on Plamen's answer.

- Arrays seem to have an empty `GenericTypeArguments` so added [GetElementType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getelementtype?view=netcore-2.2)
- Renamed class to avoid clashing with the framework class `ArrayModelBinder`.
- Added a check on the element type as it's required.
- More options for surrounding the array with brackets.

```cs
public class CustomArrayModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (!bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsEnumerableType)
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName)
            .ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(null);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var elementType = bindingContext.ModelType.GetElementType() ??
            bindingContext.ModelType.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();

        if (elementType == null)
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(elementType);

        var values = value.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x => converter.ConvertFromString(Clean(x)))
            .ToArray();

        var typedValues = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, values.Length);
        values.CopyTo(typedValues, 0);
        bindingContext.Model = typedValues;

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.Model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static string Clean(string str)
    {
        return str.Trim('(', ')').Trim('[', ']').Trim();
    }
}
```

Then use with an `IEnumerable<T>`, `IList<T>` or array `T[]`

```cs
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomArrayModelBinder))] IEnumerable<T> ids
                                                       ... T[] ids
                                                       ... IList<T> ids
```

The parameter could be in path or query with optional brackets.

```cs
[Route("resources/{ids}")]

resource/ids/1,2,3
resource/ids/(1,2,3)
resource/ids/[1,2,3]

[Route("resources")]

resource?ids=1,2,3
resource?ids=(1,2,3)
resource?ids=[1,2,3]
```

Comment: var elementType = bindingContext.ModelType.GetElementType(); within your CustomModelArrayBinder will only work on Array types. So IEnumerable<T> and List<T> will not work. This is likely fine, and it works well for me. I think your answer should be revised to remove those other options.

Comment: @iGanja updated to support IEnumerable<T>, IList<T>

Comment: Would this solution with the CustomArrayModelBinder work also if the "ids" parameter was optional, or if also some other parameters are passed with the query string?

Comment: @RickyTad Didn't test that scenario but it should work. Try it and feedback if you have issues.

Answer (score 5):

I create a new web api class, with only one action.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/accounts")]
public class AccountsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("servicesbycategoryids")]
    public IActionResult ServicesByCategoryIds([FromQuery] int[] ids)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Then use the same url as yours:

http://localhost:2443/api/accounts/servicesbycategoryids?ids=1&ids=2

It is working.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement custom model binder and the ids to be part of the URI, not in the query string.

Your endpoint could look like this:
/api/accounts/servicesbycategoryids/(1,2)

```cs
public class ArrayModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Our binder works only on enumerable types
        if (!bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsEnumerableType)
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Get the inputted value through the value provider
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).ToString();

        // If that value is null or whitespace, we return null
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(null);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // The value isn't null or whitespace,
        // and the type of the model is enumerable.
        // Get the enumerable's type, and a converter
        var elementType = bindingContext.ModelType.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments[0];
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(elementType);

        // Convert each item in the value list to the enumerable type
        var values = value.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x => converter.ConvertFromString(x.Trim()))
            .ToArray();

        // Create an array of that type, and set it as the Model value
        var typedValues = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, values.Length);
        values.CopyTo(typedValues, 0);
        bindingContext.Model = typedValues;

        // return a successful result, passing in the Model
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.Model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then use it in your action:

```cs
[HttpGet("({ids})", Name="GetAuthorCollection")]
public IActionResult GetAuthorCollection(
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ArrayModelBinder))] IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    //enter code here
}
```

Learned this from a pluralsight course: Building RESTful API with ASP.NET Core

Comment: I can highly recommend [kevin dockx](https://app.pluralsight.com/profile/author/kevin-dockx) courses!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that simply decorating the array with the `[FromQuery]` attribute is all that's needed to make the binding work. Without that attribute it fails to bind. That's it, and @kennyzx's answer above is best, but I feel like the point needed to be as simply stated as this: **`[FromQuery]` is all you need**. I don't know why these other answers went the `ModelBinder` route, maybe that is needed for some scenarios, but in my case and I'm sure with many others, the key was to not forget to apply the `[FromQuery]` attribute.

```
public ActionResult GetFoo(int id, [FromQuery] Guid[] someIds) { ... }
```

Answer (score -2):

Rather than [ab]using query string (consider 1000s of IDs), you can use `[FromBody]` instead, and pass list of IDs as a JSON array:

```
public IActionResult ServicesByCategoryIds([FromBody] int[] ids)
```

As long as OpenAPI/Swagger is concerned, a proper specification will be generated:

```
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "ids",
        "in": "body",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
```

[image]

Comment: as you can see you need to change the HTTP verb to HttpPost with the correct Content-Type because now you are passing parameters via Body. The question is related to the HttpGet verb