# C# HttpGet Enum.GetValues return liste

Tags: c#

I want to return the "Liste" but I don't know how.

```
[HttpGet("GetType")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTemplateType()
{
    var liste = Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotificationTemplateType));
    return liste;
}
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: return Ok(liste);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing an array to a asp net core web api action method HttpGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300861/passing-an-array-to-a-asp-net-core-web-api-action-method-httpget)

Comment: `return Ok(liste);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While commented hints are not wrong, You have here a walk through edition, using xUnit for the extended version first

```
public enum NotificationTemplateType
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Pigeon = 1,
    Shout = 2,
    Mail = 3,
    Team = 4,
    Skype = 5,
    Slack = 6,
    Viber = 7,
}

[Fact]
public void VerifyIsAListTest()
{
    var undefinedArray = Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotificationTemplateType));
    var specificArray = (NotificationTemplateType[])undefinedArray;
    var elementsListThoughArrayWillBeFineWhenReturningBesidesForTheController = specificArray.ToList();
    Assert.IsType<List<NotificationTemplateType>>(elementsListThoughArrayWillBeFineWhenReturningBesidesForTheController);
}
```

So Your method could be (please format better with linebreaks)

```
 [HttpGet("GetType")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetTemplateType()
 {
    var liste = ((NotificationTemplateType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(NotificationTemplateType))).ToList();
    return Ok(liste);
 }
```

Comment: so if you unit test your controller and check returned reply body contains a list it will technically fail when you run off an instantiated controller, becuse that has a type aware return type and an array is not a list, but the resulting json is the same, so comments that you can just return the array directly is true if you don't do TDD otherwise convert it like described