# How to pass an array of int in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this Web API method:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SubjectsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("children")]
    public IActionResult GetAllFromChildren([FromQuery]int[] childrenIds)
    {
        // omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call this via Ajax passing in an query string but I can't seem to get it to work. My Ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/subjects/children?childrenIds=1&childrenIds=2&childrenIds=3",
    method: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})
```

The method is called but it the int array does not get populated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It was a typo from me, I will edit in the question, I checked the code and there is a &.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try add `Name` to `[FromQuery]`, so the code should look like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SubjectsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("children")]
    public IActionResult GetAllFromChildren([FromQuery(Name="childrenIds")]int[] childrenIds)
    {
        // omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

and ajax url like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/subjects/children?childrenIds=1&childrenIds=2&childrenIds=3",
    method: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})
```