# C# Api Get Route is not able to receive Collection of String. Need Help in transferring data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I wrote the following get api Route in C# that looks like the following...

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ReadAllAppBased")]
    public List<Feedback> ReadAllAppBased(IEnumerable<string> Apps, string CAT)
    { 
            return null;
    }
```

but when I send a HTTP Request in JS I am not able to see my Collection.
Please see the following code for JS.
following...

```
    axios.get('http://localhost:63464/api/FeedBack/ReadAllAppBased',
    {
        params: { Apps: ["TESTING 3", "TESTING 123"], CAT: "TESTING" }
    })
    .then(res => {
        return res.data;
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.table(res);
    });
```

Please know that I am hitting the call in C#.
I am not able to see the data coming in for 
Apps.
I am able to see data for CAT.

Would like to know how I can fix this as I need to be able to send a Collection of string that needs to be received in C# from JS.

Comment: It needs to be in the format `{ [0].Apps: "TESTING 3", [1].Apps: "TESTING 123", CAT: "TESTING" }`

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try sending the following Url to your request in axios please...

```
axios.get("/api/FeedBack/ReadAllAppBased?Apps=TESTING%203&Apps=TESTING%20123&CAT=TESTING")
.then(res => {
    return res.data;
})
.then(res => {
    console.table(res);
});
```

For more information about binding parameters, see [Pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.stringify` as follows:

```
var data= {};
data.Apps= ["TESTING 3", "TESTING 123"];
data.CAT= "TESTING";
var dataJson= JSON.stringify(data);
```

Then pass `dataJson` as parameter.

Edit:
Forgot to consider server-side changes. 
Change `IEnumerable<string> Apps` parameter in your `ReadAllAppBased`  to `string dataJson` and in your `axios.get` replace `params` part with 
`params: {
      dataJson: dataJson
    }`.

In your `ReadAllAppBased` method use `Newtonsoft.Json` as follows:

`var params = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataJson>(dataJson);`

Where your `DataJson` class is as follows:

`class DataJson{
public List<string> Apps {get; set;}
public string CAT {get; set;}
}`

Now you `params` should contain `Apps` & `CAT`.

Hope helps.

Note: since You are sending a collection, you may better consider using `axios.post` method as you params may be too long.

Comment: Thank you for your input but I am still not able to see the data. 
I am not able to get any variable from the call

Answer (score 0):

Was missing [From Route] prior to function parameters

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ReadAllAppBased")]
    public List<Feedback> ReadAllAppBased([From Query]IEnumerable<string> Apps, [From Query] string CAT)
    { 
            return null;
    }
```

then on the JS side I would need to send what @robsonrosa has suggested.