# Web API : array is returned with a zero length from Get

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm new to Web API and I'm trying to pass an array of integers back from my Get method. Surprisingly, it was working okay when I did it on my work PC but when I re-wrote it on my home PC, it is coming as a zero length array. I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api) and all looks good, but there's something I am missing.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("test")]
public ActionResult<string> Test([FromQuery] int[] productIds)
{
    //code here
}
```

From Url:

```
https://localhost:44389/api/myController/test?productIds=1&productIds=2&productIds=3&productIds=4&productIds=5
```

It catches the route, but when I check this in debugger, `productIds.Length` is zero. Please indicate what's wrong with my url/code.

Comment: First: that's not an array of integers....

Comment: Your code says FromQuery, the answer to the question in link says FromUri

Comment: .net core uses FromQuery instead of FromUri

Comment: @Hackerman, please check the link that I gave, it also uses the same method to send a query by passing an array of integers and it works for me on another machine

Comment: @sam Ok, then try to add a `Name` to `FromQuery` like `[FromQuery(Name="productIds")]`