# Int and a List of Ints as parameters to an Asp.Net WebApi call

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send this data as a JSON Post to an Asp.Net WebApi controller called Dashboard. But with these parameters I am getting the following error. Any idea how to correct this?

```
{
    "errors": {
        "chartType": [
            "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'chartType', line 2, position 13."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "80000864-0007-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

JSON:

```
{ 
    "ChartType": 1,
    "List": [1,2,3]
}
```

Code:

```
public void Dashboard(int chartType, List<int> list)
{
    Console.Write("");
}
```

Comment: Try the [FromBody] attribute before the parameter List<int>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a class `ViewModel`

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int ChartType { get; set; }
    public List<int> List { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `FromBody` attribute.

```
public void Dashboard([FromBody]ViewModel model)
{
    Console.Write("");
}
```

Comment: Weird that it couldn't figure something as simple as that from the parameters.