# Unsupported Media Type error when using array as parameter in web api?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am running into a new error that I have never seen in Web Api

```
Response = StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[[System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], Headers:  {    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  } Message = Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details. Data = System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal InnerException =  TargetSite = System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object] ReadContentAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Type, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter], System.Net.Http.Formatting.IFormatterLogger, System.Threading.CancellationToken) StackTrace =    at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)     at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__18.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__12.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext() HelpLink =  Source = System.Web.Http HResult = -2146233088
```

Here is the action inside controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("show_many")]
[ArrayInput("ids", Separator = ',')]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetByIds(int[] ids)
{
}
```

It appears that execution doesn't reach ArrayInput or method GetByIds. I believe int array is causing this issue as a parameter. When I do a basic postman request, everything works just fine.

I am calling this endpoint from SDK via HttpClient. I also tried setting content-type in client header such as

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

but that also didnt help.

Uri looks like http://example.com/show_many?ids=1,2,3

What is the problem here?

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that this error is happening in Microsofot.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.7 but not in 5.2.3.

Furthermore I notice that with client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
only Accept header is created and not Content-Type. Content-type should be a response header, but unfortunately only adding content-type to request header actually bypasses this issue (in postman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was [ArrayInput("ids", Separator = ',')]
and its incompatibility with WebApi 5.2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I am using .Net 3.1 and I had this same issue.

the fix was this

```
[HttpGet("foo")]
public IActionResult GetFoos([FromQuery] FooType[] fooTypes)
{
     return Ok(Foo.One);
}
```

and the `queryString` was `api/myControler/foo?fooType=A&fooType=B`;

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Accept header has nothing to do with 415. Make sure that you are forming the url correctly.

You can specify [FromUri] to param as well and build your uri like `api?ids[]=1&ids[]=2`. See [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/39161417-4ae8-4763-ac8c-d54e08d853ff/web-api-2-controller-how-to-call-get-method-with-listltstringgt-as-parameter?forum=csharpgeneral).

Or if you want more control on how to form the uri, check below answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17553324/1083512

Comment: Uri format is http://example.com/show_many?ids=1,2,3 and it is accessed via postman without any issue. That is why arrayinput attribute is there for.