# Error at API end point when passing array of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-web-api

I am passing an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API but I am receiving below error.

> "An item with the same key has already been added."

This is my API endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Pen/ByPropertyIdList")]
public IQueryable<Pen> ListByPropertyIdList([FromUri] Int32[] propIds)
{
    Boolean? deleted = false;
    IQueryable < Pen > p = logic.ListByPropertyIdList(propIds, deleted).AsQueryable(); // I recieved the list of object perfectly
    return p; // returning them generates the error
}
```

This is the URL I use;

```
api/pen/ByPropertyIdList?propIds=12&propIds=348
```

The endpoint accepts my array of integers but at return point, it generates the error. I believe it is due to the `propIds`.

Comment: *I recieved the list of object perfectly* no, you are not ... you are creating the query here ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: @BugFinder no, he is passing integers in the same way as its in the answer ...

Comment: Why do you want to return a IQueryable ? ...Is there something oversea that can query the output without sending all the data ? :)

Comment: the real problem is inside `ListByPropertyIdList` or maybe when `IQueryable` (not results) is translated to JSON ... without full exception is hard to guess

Comment: @Selvin sort of except it does explain that the receiving page depending on language can handle arrays differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @LaurentLequenne!

Changing  `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` resolve the problem.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Pen/ByPropertyIdList")]
public IEnumerable<Pen> ListByPropertyIdList([FromUri] Int32[] propIds)
{
    Boolean? deleted = false;
    IEnumerable< Pen > p = logic.ListByPropertyIdList(propIds, deleted).AsEnumerable();
    return p;
}
```