# Try to bind an int[] array (as object property) from uri using route attribute web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, postman

I build an API using .Net Framework ,
I have a controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/student")]
public StudentController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IService service;
}

public StudentController(IService service)
{
   this.service = service
}

[HttpGet, Route("getStudents/{Ids:int}")]     
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetStudents([FromUri]GetStudentsRequest request)
{
   //bla bla bla 
}
```

and the class GetStudentsRequest is

```
public class GetStudentsRequest 
{
   public int[] Ids { get; set; }
}
```

I want to pass many ids in a single request, but the problem is how to pass for example 3 ids via postman??

Or I must change the attribute?

**I want only from uri not from body!**

I try this [Pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)
the highest ranking answer localhost:XXXXX/api/student/getStudents?Ids=1&Ids=2  but did not work. The different is that I have an object which have property the array.

Comment: as i know `GET` Requests looks like that `http://0.0.0.0?var1=value1&var2=value2` so give me example of how u will pass array in the url and i will help you.

Comment: yes i try http://localhost:XXXXX/api/student/getStudents?Ids=1&Ids=2 but this uri cannot  reach the contructor

Comment: You coded `Route` class .? if yes, i think u need to add to it to the `question`.

Comment: nope ,they are  the default attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solve it . for future reference if someone have the int array as property in a request object,must modify the

> Route
>   attribute

the correct is

```
[HttpGet, Route("getStudents")]  //i remove /{Ids:int} 
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetStudents([FromUri]GetStudentsRequest request)
{
   //bla bla bla 
}
```

and the uri is localhost:XXXXX/api/student/getStudents?Ids=1&Ids=2

if someone has a better solution please post it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to bind an object and not a list.

Try to change your signature like this:

`public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetStudents([FromUri]int[] ids)`

Comment: yes this modification solve the problem,but i must use object with the int array as property ..

Comment: @dimmits you can not get an object from uri or route, body is the only way afaik.