# passing variable number of multiple parameters in a HTTP Get request in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httprequest, http-get, webapi

I am trying to create a web API. As part of it I want to create a Get method which any accept any number of variable of a particular type.

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public int[] Get(int[] ids)
        {

            for(int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
            {
                ids[i] = ids[i] * 100;
            }

            return ids;
        }
    }
```

When I try to make a get request from postman using

```
https://localhost:44363/api/executionstatus?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3
```

I get an error

> {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors
> occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|39f5d965-4240af31edd27f50.","errors":{"$":["The JSON value could
> not be converted to System.Int32[]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."]}}

I have also tried  with

```
https://localhost:44363/api/executionstatus?ids=1,2,3
```

but it is also resulting in the same error. What is the correct way to pass/handle multiple parameters from a get request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you explicitly mention you want to read the variable from the query string, it will work fine in the method you are describing:

```
//.net Core
public int[] Get([FromQuery]int[] ids)

//.net Framework
public int[] Get([FromUri]int[] ids)
```

The call:

```
https://localhost:44363/api/executionstatus?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3
```

Comment: Can you try the object wrapper? Because that's how it's normally done. It allows a bit more freedom and flexibility for "complex" types. If it doesn't work I must have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Btw, I'll try to spinup a quick project to test the first method

Comment: @cvg: Cool, I hope it's sufficient for your case. I am now struggling myself on how to get that first one working XD

Comment: @cvg: I think I got it - but I am using .net core. Behavior is similar, but not identical

Comment: thanks @Stefan. I'm using .net core. using object wrapper I don't get error msgs. but the ids of data object being passed to the Get method is `null`

Comment: @cvg: sorry: I have a typo - locally I used `test` where you used `ids` - i'll correct it - the name must match

Comment: yes, I realised that test was typo and corrected at my end, but I see the ids as null using the latter approach by wrapping the data in an object

Comment: oh... I believe you'll need to add the `[FromQuery]` there as well... sorry, I seem to be a bit rusty XD

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try with string parameter

```
[HttpGet]
public int[] Get(string ids)
{
    var intIds = ids.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
    for(int i = 0; i < intIds.Length; i++)
    {
        intIds[i] = intIds[i] * 100;
    }
    return intIds;
}
```

and call your api like this

```
https://localhost:44363/api/executionstatus?ids=1,2,3
```