# Post JavaScript array with AJAX to asp.net MVC controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUsers(int projectId, int[] useraccountIds)
{
    ...
}
```

I'd like to post the parameters to the controller via AJAX. Passing the `int projectId` isn't a problem, but I can't manage to post the `int[]`.

My JavaScript code:

```
function sendForm(projectId, target) {
    $.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        url: target,
        type: "POST",
        data: { projectId: projectId, useraccountIds: new Array(1, 2, 3) },
        success: ajaxOnSuccess,
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            alert('Error message.');
        }
    });
}
```

I tried it with a test array but no success. :(
I also tried to set `traditional: true`, or `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` but no success as well ...

The `int[] useraccountIds` posted to my controller is always null.

Comment: Please post the error mesage

Comment: I've debugged the controller method and int[] useraccounts is always null.

Comment: Always best to look at the actual data being sent. Either get Fiddler, or look in your developer tools under Network (i.e. in Chrome of Firefox/Firebug).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could define a view model:

```
public class AddUserViewModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int[] userAccountIds { get; set; }
}
```

then adapt your controller action to take this view model as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUsers(AddUserViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

and finally invoke it:

```
function sendForm(projectId, target) {
    $.ajax({
        url: target,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 
            projectId: projectId, 
            userAccountIds: [1, 2, 3] 
        }),
        success: ajaxOnSuccess,
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            alert('Error message.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Even a hardcoded projectId (like 23) isn't sent to the controller.
Instead the real form data (there's a project id too) is sent. :(

Comment: This `sendForm` function over there, where are you calling it? Is it in the submit event of some form or the click event of some submit button? Did you make sure to cancel the default action of this event by returning false from it? I guess you haven't.

Comment: Hi, Is there anyway I could send javascript object to asp.net and get that class object in ApiController?

Answer (score 18):

In JS:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray.push(2);
myArray.push(3);
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/MyController/MyAction',
            data: { 'myArray': myArray.join() },
            success: refreshPage
        });
```

In MVC/ C#:

```
public PartialViewResult MyAction(string myArray)
{
   var myArrayInt = myArray.Split(',').Select(x=>Int32.Parse(x)).ToArray();
   //My Action Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using $.Ajax(), you can easily get the data from javascript to the Controller in MVC.

As like,

```
var uname = 'John Doe';

$.ajax({

        url: "/Main/getRequestID",  // This is path of your Controller with Action Result.
        dataType: "json",           // Data Type for sending the data

        data: {                     // Data that will be passed to Controller
            'my_name': uname,     // assign data like key-value pair       
             // 'my_name'  like fields in quote is same with parameter in action Result
        },

        type: "POST",               // Type of Request
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //Optional to specify Content Type.

        success: function (data) { // This function is executed when this request is succeed.
                alert(data);
        },

        error: function (data) {
                alert("Error");   // This function is executed when error occurred.
        }
)};
```

then, on the Controller side,

```
public ActionResult getRequestID(String my_name)
{

    MYDBModel myTable = new Models.MYDBModel();
    myTable.FBUserName = my_name;
    db.MYDBModel.Add(myTable);
    db.SaveChanges();              // db object of our DbContext.cs
    //return RedirectToAction(“Index”);   // After that you can redirect to some pages…
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    // Or you can get that data back after inserting into database.. This json displays all the details to our view as well.
}
```

Reference.
[Send Data from Java Script to Controller in MVC](http://dotnetternikhil.blogspot.in/2014/12/send-data-from-java-script-to.html)

Comment: Thanks Josh for updating me..
I have updated the link. please check. Actually i have moved my blog from Wordpress to blogger. So that link was broken. Now its working..

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pass an array to mvc engine, send the input multiple times. change your code to the following :

```
function sendForm(projectId, target) {
var useraccountIds = new Array(1, 2, 3);
var data = { projectId: projectId };
for (var i = 0; i < useraccountIds.length; i++) {
  $.extend(true, data, {useraccountIds: useraccountIds[i]});
}
$.ajax({
    traditional: true,
    url: target,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: ajaxOnSuccess,
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert('Error message.');
    }
});
```

}

Comment: According to the network monitor in firebug AJAX sends just the data that's really in the form but not what I specify with data...

Comment: yes, i found the solution and i edit my answer. but my code is not tested, but this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

*Put the serializable attribute on the class. Then it will try to convert the javascript object you are passing to the C# class.*

in JS:

```
{
   ProjectId = 0, 
   userAccountIds = []
}

// C#
[Serializable] 
public class AddUserViewModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int[] userAccountIds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, a ordinary class with the Serializable attribute is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work unless you specify that the ajax request (Post/Get) has the property
`traditional` is set to true.
Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489461/pass-array-to-mvc-action-via-ajax) for more details.