# jQuery post wont post data to ASP.NET API Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having a nightmare of a time sending data to ASP.NET Controller via jquery post. This is what the data looks like after JSON.stringify:

```
[{"scheduleTaskID":"203","task":"Permit","baselineDate":"4/6/2005 8:00:00 AM","scheduledDate":"4/6/2005 8:00:00 AM","actualDate":"4/6/2005 8:00:00 AM","finishedDate":"","selected":"on"},{"scheduleTaskID":"195","task":"Office Files","baselineDate":"7/13/2005 8:00:00 AM","scheduledDate":"7/13/2005 8:00:00 AM","actualDate":"7/13/2005 8:00:00 AM","finishedDate":"","selected":"on"},{"scheduleTaskID":"196","task":"Foundation","baselineDate":"7/27/2005 8:00:00 AM","scheduledDate":"7/27/2005 8:00:00 AM","actualDate":"8/13/2005 8:00:00 AM","finishedDate":"","selected":"on"},{"scheduleTaskID":"197","task":"Framing","baselineDate":"8/5/2005 8:00:00 AM","scheduledDate":"8/5/2005 8:00:00 AM","actualDate":"8/23/2005 8:00:00 AM","finishedDate":"","selected":"on"},{"scheduleTaskID":"198","task":"Finishes Exterior","baselineDate":"8/26/2005 8:00:00 AM","scheduledDate":"8/26/2005 8:00:00 AM","actualDate":"9/14/2005 8:00:00 AM","finishedDate":"","selected":"on"},{"scheduleTaskID":"199","task":"Drywall","baselineDate":"9/2/2005 8:00:00 AM","scheduledDate":"9/2/2005 8:00:00 AM","actualDate":"9/16/2005 8:00:00 AM","finishedDate":"","selected":"on"},{"scheduleTaskID":"200","task":"Flooring","baselineDate":"9/1/2005 8:00:00 AM","scheduledDate":"9/1/2005 8:00:00 AM","actualDate":"9/20/2005 8:00:00 AM","finishedDate":"","selected":"on"},{"scheduleTaskID":"201","task":"General Finish","baselineDate":"9/12/2005 8:00:00 AM","scheduledDate":"9/12/2005 8:00:00 AM","actualDate":"","finishedDate":"","selected":"on"},{"scheduleTaskID":"202","task":"Final PDI","baselineDate":"10/11/2005 8:00:00 AM","scheduledDate":"10/11/2005 8:00:00 AM","actualDate":"","finishedDate":"","selected":"on"},{"scheduleTaskID":"203","task":"Permit","baselineDate":"4/6/2005 8:00:00 AM","scheduledDate":"4/6/2005 8:00:00 AM","actualDate":"4/6/2005 8:00:00 AM","finishedDate":"","selected":"on"},{}]
```

This is how I am trying to pass that data:

```
$.post("/api/update/", JSON.stringify( array ), alert('success'), 'json');
```

This is my ASP.NET API Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public dynamic Post(List<CellModel> cells)
        {
        }
```

This is what CellModel is:

```
public class CellModel
    {
        public string scheduleTaskID { get; set; }
        public string task { get; set; }
        public string baselineDate { get; set; }
        public string scheduledDate { get; set; }
        public string actualDate { get; set; }
        public string finishedDate { get; set; }
        public bool selected { get; set; }
    }
```

When I put a break point in the controller after `public dynamic Post(List<CellModel> cells)` it says cells is `cells Count = 0`...I put `return false;` after my post call to see a network call, it says the Status Code is 301 Moved Permanently:

[image]

This is how I am getting this data:

```
$("#form").submit(function (event) {
            var array = [];
            $('#form > table > tbody  > tr').each(function (elem) {
                var item = {
                    scheduleTaskID: $(this).find("td > #scheduleTaskID").val(),
                    task: $(this).find("td > #task").val(),
                    baselineDate: $(this).find("td > #baselineDate").val(),
                    scheduledDate: $(this).find("td > #scheduledDate").val(),
                    actualDate: $(this).find("td > #actualDate").val(),
                    finishedDate: $(this).find("td > #finishedDate").val(),
                    selected: $(this).find("td > #selected").val(),
                };
                array.push(item);
            });

            $.post("/api/update/", JSON.stringify(array), alert('success'), 'json');
            return false;

        });
```

Comment: The URL to which you ware posting is `update` but the endpoint is `Post`, according to the code posted. Also, it appears as though you have multiple elements with the same id. This is a bad thing in HTML.

Comment: Yes multiple elements have a same id and I need to pass it in that way

Comment: I also don't understand how the Post method gets called.  Looks like the data should be posted to the 'update' method...

Comment: its an api controller so the url should look like /api/<controllername>/<methodname> I get the same results if the put in the method name or take it out. the contoller is called UpdateController...only update should be in the url

Comment: >net web api uses magic words for crud . if the method starts with the verb then it is considered the verb public Task<Object> Post(Object object) is a Post

Comment: Maybe it's the `"on"` for `"selected"`. You might want to use `.is(':checked')` rather than `.val()` if it's a checkbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST`ing a straight-up JSON array to an MVC controller doesn't work. The solution is to use the long-form AJAX jQuery method, include the `traditional:true` option, and structure your JSON data *and* model differently - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782417/post-javascript-array-with-ajax-to-asp-net-mvc-controller).

Re the model: the parameter to your controller action should not be an array - it should be a model class which *contains* and array member - and of course your JSON should mirror this structure.