# passing an array of int to MVC controller using ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

What am I doing wrong here?

I can successfully pass 4 bool params to a controller. Now I want to pass an array of int to my controller but it doesn't work - I've left my working code in the example(commented out) so you can see I'm not changing that much - I think I'm missing something simple (it is 17:44 afterall!!!). I can see the array is populated using the `alert(rolesChecked);` statement:

```
var rolesChecked = [];
$('[type="checkbox"].role-checkbox').each(function () {
    if (this.checked)
    {
        rolesChecked.push($(this).val());
    }
});

alert(rolesChecked);

//var administrator = $('#cbAdministrator').is(":checked");
//var manager = $('#cbManager').is(":checked");
//var technician = $('#cbTechnician').is(":checked");
//var transcriber = $('#cbTranscriber').is(":checked");

if (rolesChecked.count > 0){//administrator || manager || technician || transcriber) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetFutureHolidays", "Employee")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        // we set cache: false because GET requests are often cached by browsers
        // IE is particularly aggressive in that respect
        cache: false,
        data: {
            roleIdXXXs: rolesChecked
            //includeAdministrator: administrator,
            //includeManager: manager,
            //includeTechnician: technician,
            //includeTranscriber: transcriber
        },
        success: function (data) {

            //do something...
        }
    });
}
```

Controller Action:

```
public string GetFutureHolidays(List<int> roleIdXXXs)//bool includeAdministrator, bool includeManager, bool includeTechnician, bool includeTranscriber)
{
    //do something
}
```

with the old code, the controller action would be hit... with the array, it never gets hit... What am I missing here...

also, I think `List<int> roleIdXXXs` should be fine, but I also tried `List<string>`, `int[]` and `string[]` in case it isn't!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782417/post-javascript-array-with-ajax-to-asp-net-mvc-controller?rq=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add the `traditional: true` ajax option to post back an array to the collection

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetFutureHolidays", "Employee")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: { roleIdXXXs: rolesChecked },
    traditional: true, // add this
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Refer also the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497093/what-is-traditional-style-of-param-serialization-in-jquery) for more detail on what the options does and the form data it generates.

Comment: Awesome, thanks - for anyone wondering, the above works and controller can be: `public string GetFutureHolidays(List<int> roleIdXXXs)`

Comment: I've chosen this as the answer because I don't need to deserialise in the controller from a json string.

Comment: I've been looking for this answer a really long time

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement, instead of rolesChecked.count, use rolesChecked.length

Comment: Thanks - you're the only one who spotted the count error... I'm new to javascript and rolesChecked.count is undefined!!!! so the ajax query wasn't actually called!!!! using rolesChecked.length means the ajax query is called and the controller action is hit. However I still needed to set `traditional: true` or the array isn't passed to the controller action, just null. Thanks

Comment: I tested with your code and only changed count to length and everything worked. Not sure why you have to add traditional.

Comment: it was always null without `traditional` - seems weird that it's ok for you... I'll retest if I get a chance.

Comment: What MVC version are you using? I don't know if that will have anything to do with it  or not. I used 5 for testing. I also tried it with `List<int> roleIdXXXs` and it worked too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't submit a list like this from Ajax, the quickest fix in the process you are using is to use serialization-desalinization process, you can send it as

> `roleIdXXXs: JSON.stringify(rolesChecked)`

on Action:

```
public ActionResult GetFutureHolidays(string rolesChecked)
{
    var test = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<int>>(rolesChecked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON.stringify() on you AJAX call lice this:

```
data: {
            roleIdXXXs: JSON.stringify(rolesChecked)
            //includeAdministrator: administrator,
            //includeManager: manager,
            //includeTechnician: technician,
            //includeTranscriber: transcriber
        }
```