# Pass c# list to the controller via JS

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I do not have idea how to pass the full list by the Ajax. So i have c# list in the cshtml file and I want to pass it to the controller via Ajax. I know how to Pass simple variable, but don't know how to pass full list of objects. there is a simple js script:

```
$.get("/home/function?List=" + SthList, function (r) {
    $("#Table").html(r);
});
```

It should not work, because `SthList` isn't SJ object. But when I want to use razor it does not work anyway.

There is a controller

```
public ActionResult function(List<Object> List)
{
    ...
    return PartialView(sth);
}
```

do you have any tips for me?

Comment: u can use json.net library.

Comment: What is the model and its properties. And what is `SthList`

Comment: SthList is a c# List<object>, it isn't really important what is the model. This questuion does not depend on this.

Comment: Of course it does!

Comment: It would make more sense to put a list in a form and POST it.

Comment: The model in the view is a list of few model, because I need to pass few models to the view. Yes, I know that I can POST it, but I want to change table dynamically, and I have few List to pass to the controller, this is just simplyfied model what I want to achieve. The question is simple, how to pass c# list by the ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to transform your `C#` Array into a `JsArray`. To do that you need to mix razor and javascript.

There is a question for how to do that ( how to convert c# array into a js array?) [Mix Razor and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code)

The other problem is passing array via ajax  to the  controller.

There is another question for that. [Post array to mvc controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782417/post-javascript-array-with-ajax-to-asp-net-mvc-controller)

So you can find your answer with this questions.