# How to pass the ajax result data into jquery datatable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I want to pass the result data of ajax page  to jquery datatable  function,Please suggest me the correct syntax how to pass the result into the datatable function:

```
function getResultsMsr(action, msrDel) {
            if(action == 'search') {
            $.ajax({
                     url: 'getResult.php',
                       type: 'POST',
                       data: {
                             formName:'afscpMsr',
                            action:'search',
                            field_nm: document.getElementById('msrdet').value,
                             field_value:document.getElementById('srhmsr').value    
                         }
                      }).done(function(result_data){

                          var  data= result_data;
                          $('#example').dataTable( {
                            "processing": true,
                            "serverSide": true
                    });

                    });
```

Table which is diplay the data and column name is:

```
   <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
                    <thead>
                         <tr>
                           <th>Customer Name</th>
                           <th>Feature Order No</th>
                           <th>NCP Account Number</th>
                           <th>Mcn Code</th>
                           <th>Sales Person</th>
                          <!--  <th>Due Date</th> --> 
                           <th>Status</th>
                            <th>MSR Id</th>
                            <th>Action </th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                 </table>
```

Ajax page which passes the result  to be  displayed in datatable ,this result is in json format :

```
  if($_POST['action'] == 'search')
  {
    $col_nm = $_POST['field_nm'];
    $srch_val = $_POST['field_value'];
     if($srch_val == 'Yes') {
         $srch_val = 'Y';
     } elseif ($srch_val == 'No'){
        $srch_val = 'N';
    }
    $result = $afscpMsrMod->getMsrDetails($col_nm, $srch_val,$page,$start);
    $totalCont = $afscpMsrMod->getTotalCountOfMsrDetails($col_nm, $srch_val);
    $totalCont= ceil($totalCont/10);
    $newarray = array(
        "draw"            => intval( ""),
        "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalCont ),
        "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalCont ),
        "data"            => json_encode($result[0])
    );
    echo json_encode($newarray);
```

Comment: follow the examples on dataTables site. You need to refine your initialization options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can use in this way

```
    var opts =
        {
            'ajax'    :
            {
                'url': 'serverSideTableProviderPage',
                'type': 'POST',
                'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'data':function(data)
                 {
                       return data = JSON.stringify(data);
                 }
            },
            'pagingType': 'simple',
            [more options ...]
        }
    $('table').dataTable(opts);
```

For more info [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262677/modelbinding-parameter-list-in-mvc/23832492#23832492)

Comment: I have to pass the data parameters to ajax call  :  data: {
                           formName:'afscpMsr',
                           action:'search',
                           field_nm:  document.getElementById('msrdet').value,
field_value:document.getElementById('srhmsr').value                    }

Comment: How to pass the data parameter to ajax call example action:search,field_nm: document.getElementById('msrdet').value

Comment: Please suggest me the answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using aaData property:

Here you can find information abour various data sources for datatables:

[JS array as datasource in datatables](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

[Server side data processing](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

[Ajax source](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

[DOM zero configuration](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/dom.html)

```
 function getResultsMsr(action, msrDel) {
        if(action == 'search') {
        $.ajax({
                 url: 'getResult.php',
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: {
                         formName:'afscpMsr',
              function getResultsMsr(action, msrDel) {
        if(action == 'search') {
        $.ajax({
                 url: 'getResult.php',
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: {
                         formName:'afscpMsr',
                        action:'search',
                        field_nm: document.getElementById('msrdet').value,
                         field_value:document.getElementById('srhmsr').value    
                     }
                  }).done(function(result_data){

                      var  data= result_data;
                      $('#example').dataTable( {
                        "processing": true,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "aaData":data
                });

                });          action:'search',
                        field_nm: document.getElementById('msrdet').value,
                         field_value:document.getElementById('srhmsr').value    
                     }
                  }).done(function(result_data){

                      var  data= result_data;
                      $('#example').dataTable( {
                        "processing": true,
                        "serverSide": true
                });

                });
```

Comment: I have check these above links , but they havent mention the data parameter passing in ajax call.