# Ajax POST not posting list

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing data to controller through Ajax call.
Following is the ajax code:

```
var month_List = [];
$('#dojMonths :selected').each(function (i, selectedItem) {
  month_List[i] = $(selectedItem).text();
});
var from_Month = $("#fromKPAMonthPicker").val();
var from_Year = $("#fromKPAYearPicker").val();
var to_Month = $("#toKPAMonthPicker").val();
var to_Year = $("#toKPAYearPicker").val();
$.ajax({
  url: '/Home/_DataByFromTo',
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    doj_Month_List: month_List,
    from_Month: from_Month,
    from_Year: from_Year,
    to_Month: to_Month,
    to_Year: to_Year
  },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function (data) {
    $("#divList").html(data);
  }
});
```

Controller action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _DataByFromTo(List<Int32> doj_Month_List, Int16 from_Month, Int16 from_Year, Int16 to_Month, Int16 to_Year)
{
  return View();
}
```

It was working in my old code perfectly fine. I don't know whats the problem. because all data are passing perfectly except this array of jquery.

Comment: Try to use int[] as method argument rather than a list.

Comment: Or try setting tradition: true http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489461/pass-array-to-mvc-action-via-ajax

Comment: What kind of element $('#dojMonths')  is?

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan well setting tradition is working. pls post ur comment as ans. so I can accept d ans.

Comment: @DKS I have added my comment as an answer. I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable deep serialization of objects you need to set `traditional` property to `true`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/_DataByFromTo',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
    doj_Month_List: month_List,
    from_Month: from_Month,
    from_Year: from_Year,
    to_Month: to_Month,
    to_Year: to_Year
    },
    dataType: "html",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#divList").html(data);
    }
});
```

When set to `true` it results in a shallow serialization.
Following link might be of help.
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 0):

try using push

```
var month_List = [];
$('#dojMonths :selected').each(function (i, selectedItem) {
    month_List.push($(selectedItem).text());
});
```