# pass array in javascript object to mvc controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript object like:

```
var data={
 Manager:name,
 ID:id,
 EmployeeNames:arrayEmployees
};
```

As you can see, name and id are simple strings but EmployeeNames is an array object. I have the ajax call like this:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "GetManagerEmployees",
      content: "application/json;",
      dataType: "json",
      data: data,
      success: 
      error: 
});
```

In the controller I have a method GetManagerEmployees(Data data) with parameter of type Data which contains all the properties:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<string> EmployeeNames { get; set; }
```

I'm getting data.EmployeeNames as null in my controller, what am I doing wrong here? Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Show what is your `arrayEmployees` variable

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/5489518/4772988 also

Comment: Show your controller

Comment: @suvroc var arrayEmployees= new Array(); arrayEmployees.push("Name1");

Comment: Have you tried to change List<string> to a string array? (string[]). If it is just strings you don't need the overload of a List.

Comment: @Imad my controller method is like this: [HttpPost] public void GetManagerEmployees(Data data)

Comment: Yes I have tried with string[] but no use its null

Comment: Are you 'stringfying' your data argument before send it to controller? 
newData = JSON.stringify({ 'data': data });

Comment: I tried to stringify but control does not reach the controller if stringify is used anywhere

Comment: have you tried ajax option: `traditional:true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created a project with this structure and It's working:

Note that traditional:true on the jquery ajax call:

> As of jQuery 1.4, the $.param() method serializes deep objects recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality globally by setting jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;.

Source: [jQuery.param() Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

Also, you don't need a List for that. Just use a simple string array in your model.

**Javascript**

```
$("#myBtn").click(function () {

                var arrayEmployees = new Array();

                arrayEmployees.push("Name1");

                var data = {
                    "Manager": 'John',
                    "id": 1,
                    "EmployeeNames": arrayEmployees
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    traditional:true,
                    url: "PostManager",
                    content: "application/json;",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: data,
                    success: function () {
                    }
                });
            });
```

**Controller/Model**

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostManager(Data  data)
{

}

public class Data
{
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string[] EmployeeNames { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I add traditional:true then it does not call the controller, im using jquery-1.8 version, do I need to add any other version of jquery script?

Comment: $.param(arrayEmployees) is returning undefined elements in the array

Comment: Just created a fresh MVC project, using jquery-1.10.2. Do you see any errors in the console? Make sure you have your  url correct.