# Passing array of objects to Controller Action using jQuery ajax request using .NET Core 2.2 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Array of objects after stringifying is not passed to controller action and the parameter of action (the model) is `null`.

I have tried many solutions given to this problem in `StackOverflow` but none of these solution solved my problem. I provided the links which I tried:

[Pass array to mvc Action via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489461/pass-array-to-mvc-action-via-ajax?rq=1)

[pass array in javascript object to mvc controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131308/pass-array-in-javascript-object-to-mvc-controller?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here is my code

`JavaScript Code`

```
$("#FormSubmit").click(function () {
    var datalist = [];

    $("#MarksTable tbody tr").each(function () {

        var obj = {};
        obj.StudentID = 1;
        obj.ExamTimeTableID = 1;
        obj.ClassActivity = $(this).find("td:eq(5) input").val();
        obj.IsPresent = $(this).find("td:eq(7) input").val();
        obj.Assignment = $(this).find("td:eq(6) input").val();
        obj.MidTerm = $(this).find("td:eq(3) input").val();
        obj.Final = $(this).find("td:eq(4) input").val();

        datalist.push(obj);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("InsertData", "Examination")",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(datalist),
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

`Action of Controller:`

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult InsertData([FromBody] List<StudentMarksList> obj)
{

    DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
    .
    .
    .
    return Json(param.Get<string>("msg"));
}
```

The Model:

```
public class StudentMarksList
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int ExamTimeTableID { get; set; }
    public int ClassActivity { get; set; }
    public int IsPresent { get; set; }
    public int Assignment { get; set; }
    public int MidTerm { get; set; }
    public int Final { get; set; }
}
```

Request Payload:

```
[,…]
0: {StudentID: 1, ExamTimeTableID: 1, ClassActivity: 3, IsPresent: 0, Assignment: 2, MidTerm: 5, Final: 4}
Assignment: 2
ClassActivity: 3
ExamTimeTableID: 1
Final: 4
IsPresent: 0
MidTerm: 5
StudentID: 1
```

Request Payload source:

```
[{"StudentID":1,"ExamTimeTableID":1,"ClassActivity":3,"IsPresent":0,"Assignment":2,"MidTerm":5,"Final":4}]
```

The `obj` should contains the passed objects but it is `null`.

Any Help???

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 not allowing post complex `JSON` data to the controller you need to create form field and post the data.

Comment: Please include the code of `StudentMarksList`

Comment: @itminus I have included the code of `StudentMarksList`

Comment: Have you tried setting the Ajax option `traditional` to true?

Comment: @jishansiddique But it works manually

Comment: @AsrarAhmadEhsan yes it's work manually but when you prepared JSON object and post more complex data such as list not post the data.

Comment: Did you check that your browser sends correct JSON to the correct endpoint and you don't have an error in the rest of your Javascript/HTML. Please post your startup code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edit]**
Change the js as below:

```
    function toInt(str){
        var i = parseInt(str);
        return i ? i : 0;
    }

    $("#MarksTable tbody tr").each(function () {

        var obj = {};
        obj.StudentID = 1;
        obj.ExamTimeTableID = 1;
        obj.ClassActivity = toInt( $(this).find("td:eq(5) input").val());
        obj.IsPresent =toInt(  $(this).find("td:eq(7) input").val());
        obj.Assignment = toInt( $(this).find("td:eq(6) input").val());
        obj.MidTerm =toInt(  $(this).find("td:eq(3) input").val());
        obj.Final = toInt( $(this).find("td:eq(4) input").val());

        datalist.push(obj);
    });
```

This will make sure the empty input to `0` instead of `null`.

---

<strike>That's because on your server side you're declaring the `ClassActivity`/`ClassActivity`/`Assignment`/... as `int` type but your js send all them as `string`. For example, the Payload sent to server will be something like:</strike>

```
[{"StudentID":1,"ExamTimeTableID":1,"ClassActivity":"3","Assignment":"aa","MidTerm":"333333333","Final":"3333"},{"StudentID":1,"ExamTimeTableID":1,"ClassActivity":"","Assignment":"s","MidTerm":"2","Final":"1"},{"StudentID":1,"ExamTimeTableID":1,"ClassActivity":"3","Assignment":"","MidTerm":"2","Final":"1"}]
```

Please either change the property type or convert the `$(this).find("td:eq(7) input").val()` result (a `string`) to `int`/`bool`/... type before sending them.

Comment: I send a single object manually with string value to `ClassActivity` and others which will be numbers it works. the value of these fields are numbers

Comment: @AsrarAhmadEhsan Could you please press `F12` and inspect the `Network` and show us the real payload sent to the server ?

Comment: @AsrarAhmadEhsan I copy & paste your code and create a new project using ASP.NET Core `2.2.402`, but the payload ```[{"StudentID":1,"ExamTimeTableID":1,"ClassActivity":3,"IsPresent":0,"Assignment":2,"MidTerm":5,"Final":4}]``` works for me.  Is there a way/project online that reproduces the same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this property to your ajax call:

```
traditional:true,
```

such that your ajax call looks like this at the end

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("InsertData", "Examination")",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    traditional:true,
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(datalist),
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (errormessage) {
        alert(errormessage.responseText);
    }
});
```

Happy coding. Hope it helps someone just as it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also.

> cshtml page you need to add one `form` tag like eg.

```
<div style="display:none;">
<form id="FormPost"></form>
</div>
```

> Jquery Code

```
$("#FormSubmit").click(function () {

    $("#FormPost").html('');
    $("#MarksTable tbody tr").each(function (index,elem) {

       addHidden("StudentID["+index+"]","1");
       addHidden("ExamTimeTableID["+index+"]","1");
       addHidden("ClassActivity["+index+"]",$(this).find("td:eq(5) input").val());
       addHidden("IsPresent["+index+"]",$(this).find("td:eq(7) input").val());
       addHidden("Assignment["+index+"]",$(this).find("td:eq(6) input").val());
       addHidden("MidTerm["+index+"]",$(this).find("td:eq(3) input").val());
       addHidden("Final["+index+"]",$(this).find("td:eq(4) input").val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("InsertData", "Examination")",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $("#FormPost").serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
});

function addHidden(key, value) {   
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = key;
    input.value = value;
    $("#FormPost").appendChild(input);
}
```

> Action of Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult InsertData(List<StudentMarksList> obj)
{

    DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
    .
    .
    .
    return Json(param.Get<string>("msg"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be dynamic value of one of property in object below is not a number, it contains some alphabet characters.

```
var obj = {};
        obj.StudentID = 1;
        obj.ExamTimeTableID = 1;
        obj.ClassActivity = $(this).find("td:eq(5) input").val();//this value could be not a number, ex: 'abc' text
        obj.IsPresent = $(this).find("td:eq(7) input").val();
        obj.Assignment = $(this).find("td:eq(6) input").val();
        obj.MidTerm = $(this).find("td:eq(3) input").val();
        obj.Final = $(this).find("td:eq(4) input").val();
```

It will be reason that Asp.Net cannot deserialize your action parameter item to object of StudentMarksList.

If above is not the root cause, you can follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948375/how-to-log-asp-net-core-input-json-serialization-errors) to log out serialization errors to have further investigation.