# Passing int array to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have a JavaScript function where I pass 4 arrays, each of these is of the type
[1, 2] with only int values inside or [] with no values inside. these are passed into an `Url.Action` command.

```
function Filter(locations, machines, severities, messages) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Filter", "ActiveMessages")?' + $.param({ 
        locations: locations, machines: machines, severities: severities, messages: messages });
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) { }
    });
}
```

I tried to build the parameters using `$.param()`. but this doesn't generate the parameters i'm expecting, I get something like this: `"/ActiveMessages/Filter?locations%5B%5D=1"`

I also tried doing this:

```
decodeURIComponent($.param({ locations: filterlocations, machines: filtermachines, severities: filterseverities, messages: filtermessages }))
```

Then I get something like this:
`"/ActiveMessages/Filter?locations[]=1&locations[]=2"`

Are there any other ways to parse such an array into an url?

Receiving happens in the controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Filter(int[] locations, int[] machines, int[] severities, int[] messages)
{
    //TODO filter
}
```

This gets called but the parameters are null;

when I started out I used this which works for a single value but needs to be extended to an array.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Filter", "ActiveMessages")' + '?locations=' + locations + '&machines=' + machines + '&severities=' + severities + '&messages=' + messages;
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass them by URL?

Comment: what other way would you recommend? i thought it would be the easiest way since the data isn't private

Comment: I suggest to pass them with an AJAX POST and include all arrays on data property. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5489534/6157222

Comment: Yes. Just use POST. You should pretty much *always* use POST with an AJAX call involving data.

Comment: If you did want to do this as a query string, then you need to use `$.param({ ..... }, true);` - your missing the 2nd parameter - [refer documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) (and the `traditional: true` option would be pointless since you not sending any data in the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best practise for a post action will be to use the body to send parameters for post (Note the [FromBody] annotation of paramters):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Filter([FromBody] int[] locations, [FromBody] int[] machines, [FromBody] int[] severities, [FromBody] int[] messages)
```

the parameters needs to be specified in the body of the ajax call:

```
function Filter(locations, machines, severities, messages) {
     var url = '@Url.Action("Filter", "ActiveMessages")';
     $.ajax({
          url: url,
          method: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify({ locations: locations, machines: machines, severities: severities, messages: messages }),
          traditional: true,
          success: function (data) {
     }});
 }
```

Comment: `[FromBody]` is unnecessary here. The method only allows POST, so the data will of course come from the post body.

Comment: I've implemented this but i'm still getting null as value in my controller

Comment: I've build the data like this : data: { 'locations': locations, 'machines': machines, 'severities': severities, 'messages': messages } as suggested by 
                 – Ivan Franco . Now i'm getting the data in my controller

Answer (score 2):

```
var locations = [1,2];
var machines = [3,4];
var severities = [5,6];
var messages = [7,8];

$.ajax({
     url: @Url.Action("Filter", "ActiveMessages"),
     method: 'POST',
     data: { 
            locations: locations, 
            machines: machines, 
            severities: severities, 
            messages: messages 
     },
     success: function (data) {
     }
});
```

In this case, no need to stringify :)

Answer (score 2):

While what the others say is totally true (body is made for that) sometimes it's still good to have a choice. The Problem with your query was that the keyword `machines=` (or locations etc.) must be repeated for each array value. Something like this would work:

```
const machines = [1, 2];
const locations = [3, 4];

function formatParamArray(array, name) {
  return `${name}=` + array.reduce((acc, cur) => `${acc}&${name}=${cur}`);
}

var url = '@Url.Action("Filter", "ActiveMessages")?'+formatParamArray(machines, 'machines')+'&'+formatParamArray(locations, 'locations');
```