# Ajax Array sent to .NET Api Controller always zero length

Tags: c#, ajax

I have one ajax call :

```
  var arr = [1, 2, 3];
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:14506/api/Lanche/Montar",
      type: "POST",
      data: { id: arr },
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
      }
  });
```

Sending to one WebApi Controller

```
public decimal Montar( int[] id )
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                // code here
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

But always this id comes with 0 items, what´s wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass array to mvc Action via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489461/pass-array-to-mvc-action-via-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `[FromBody]` to force Web API to read type from the request body

```
public decimal Montar([FromBody] int[] id )
 {
    if (id != null)
    {
                // code here
    }
    return 0;
 }
```