# How pass int array from jquery ajax to asp.net mvc action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have tried many stackoverflow posts, but I have always the same result.
The passed int array always null.

[Pass array to mvc Action via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489461/pass-array-to-mvc-action-via-ajax)

Here the asp.net mvc action which accept the int array of ids.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Downloads(int[] ids){
    return RedirectToAction("Exports", ids);
}
```

This is the ajax call, which is send the values.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Downloads")';
var values = [1,2,3];
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    traditional: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({ids: values })
});
```

I have no idea what I make wrong.
I have passed the ajax's date like a simple array: `data: values` or without stringify, but the asp.net mvc never accept the int array. It seems the `traditional` parameter of `ajax` object does not do anything.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in this case I get a 'Invalid JSON primitive ids' error message. OK, content-type had to be removed too.

Comment: Glad you got it working, I added it as an answer for you below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send values using traditional encoding then you shouldn't JSON encode the data you're sending. As such, remove the `JSON.stringify()` call, as well as the `contentType`. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
  traditional: true,
  data: { ids: values }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove JSON.stringify it will work.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(int[] ids)
{
   return Json("Integers. " + ids);
}
```

//In Jquery please put this.

```
var PostData = {};
PostData.ids = [1, 2, 3, 5];
var ajaxOptions = {
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Test", "Settings")',//Actionname, ControllerName
        data: PostData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {

        }
};
$.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```